# Calling async method synchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have an `async` method:

```
public async Task<string> GenerateCodeAsync()
{
    string code = await GenerateCodeService.GenerateCodeAsync();
    return code;
}
```

I need to call this method synchronously, from another synchronous method.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I run an async Task<T> method synchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously)

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler solution, thinking that asp.net handled this much easier than writing so many lines of code

Comment: Why don't just embrace async code? Ideally you'd want more async code, not less.

Comment: [Why don't just embrace async code?] Ha, it may be precisely because one is embracing async code that they need this solution as large parts of the project get converted! You cannot rebuild Rome in a day.

Comment: Well, next step. I need to be able to kill thread, running  my synchronous method so GenerateCodeAsync must be killed too

Comment: The answers given here are incorrect. You can still deadlock on .Result, even if you schedule on the thread pool, because you yourself can be running on the threadpool. It really boils down to mixing async + synchronous code is a really bad idea. If possible, consider making the root async and wrapping your long-running synchronous work either with the long running flag or a TaskCompletionSource and your own worker threads that process a queue and signal completion.

Comment: @NicholasPetersen sometimes 3rd-party library can force you to do this. Example building dynammic messages in WithMessage method out of FluentValidation. There is no async API for this due to library design - WithMessage overloads are static. Other methods of passing dynamic arguments to WithMessage are strange.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I am not sure this is the correct answer, as calling `.Result` will result in a deadlock.

Comment: the update I provided only mentions that `.NET` is solving my question in the `HttpClient` implementation - I just don't know how it does it. I am not mentioning/suggesting that the `.Result` should be used, because, as also mentioned in the upvoted answer, it doesn't. I am not sure what you want me to do. Should I remove the "Update" header from my question, so it doesn't distract the people from reading the suggested answers?

Comment: OK, I updated the question.

Comment: it looks good. I am not emotionality attached to this question, other than the fact that it reminds me how much time has passed since I had this problem :) there was a typo, I updated it.

Comment: you are correct. I'll update it again.

Comment: Catalin FYI I deleted all my "meta" comments, to keep the question clear and shiny! :-)

Answer (score 348):

You can run the method in a thread pool thread and use the task's awaiter to block the calling thread until the asynchronous operation has completed:

```
string code = Task.Run(() => GenerateCodeAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

---

**Why is `.Result` not good enough?**

You might be tempted to just access the `Result` property of the task to achieve the same result:

```
string code = GenerateCodeAsync().Result;
```

This naive approach, however, has two drawbacks:

1. In some cases this leads to a deadlock: Your call to `Result` blocks the main thread, thereby preventing the remainder of the async code to execute. This can be avoided by [adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` at the right places](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), but doing this correctly is [not trivial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/).

   We avoid this issue by calling `Task.Run` to execute the asynchronous method in a thread pool thread.
2. `.Result` (or `.Wait()` for tasks without a return value) will wrap any Exception that may be thrown in your asynchronous method in an `AggregateException`.

   We avoid this issue by [calling `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38530225/4313030).

Comment: If invoking `result` risks a deadlock, then when *is* it safe to get the result?  Does every asynchronous call require `Task.Run` or `ConfigureAwait(false)`?

Comment: There is no "main thread" in ASP.NET (unlike a GUI app), but the deadlock is still possible because of [how](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23062154/1768303) `AspNetSynchronizationContext.Post` serializes async continuations: `Task newTask = _lastScheduledTask.ContinueWith(_ => SafeWrapCallback(action)); _lastScheduledTask = newTask;`

Comment: @RobertHarvey: If you have no control over the implementation of the async method you're blocking on, then yes, you should wrap it with `Task.Run` to stay safe. Or use something like [`WithNoContext`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28410046/1768303) to reduce redundant thread switching.

Comment: NOTE: Calling `.Result` can still deadlock if the caller is on the thread pool itself. Take a scenario where the Thread Pool is of size 32 and 32 tasks are running and `Wait()/Result` waiting on a yet-to-be-scheduled 33rd task that wants to run on one of the waiting threads.

Comment: @Warty - to clarify, for the deadlock to happen, the thread pool would have to re-use *the same thread* that is waiting for the result. This will happen rarely - which is bad, because when it does happen, it won't be obvious what went wrong.

Comment: As mentioned by others, this can result in random deadlock conditions - totally do not recommend it.

Comment: @FrankThomas: What alternative *do* you recommend? (Serious question) I'll gladly update my answer with a solution which does not risk deadlocks.

Comment: @Heinzi The only solid solution is to make a program flow constantly async from start to finish. If that is not possible. The only solution I found that didn't seem to generate deadlocks is answered below:

var task = Task.Run(() => GenerateCodeAsync()); 
task.Wait();
string code = task.Result;

Comment: @FrankThomas: Even there deadlock-freeness is not guaranteed, since `Task.Run` uses the thread pool (see ToolmakerSteve's comments on this and other answers). In addition, Task.Run executes the code in a different thread, which might cause GenerateCodeAsync to behave differently. It's really a pity that there is no built-in, deadlock-free method to execute async code synchronously.

Comment: @Heinzi I hear you mate. It's forced me to really decide to go async all the way or none of the way.

Comment: Please, be aware that calling `.Result` wraps the Exceptions that may be thrown. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38530225/4313030 and consider using `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead.

Answer (score 55):

You can get the `TaskAwaiter` with the [`GetAwaiter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter) method, and wait synchronously for the completion of the task with the blocking [`GetResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.getresult) method:

```
string code = GenerateCodeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

**Important:** The `GetResult` method has blocking behavior only for the `Task`/`Task<T>` awaitable types, not for the [`ValueTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask)/`ValueTask<T>` structs. You should never call this method directly on [value tasks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/) (these types have [strict usage limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask?#remarks)). What you can do is to use first the [`AsTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask.astask) and convert the value tasks to normal reference tasks. Here is an example of synchronously waiting the `ValueTask` returned by the [`Timer.DisposeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.disposeasync) method:

```
timer.DisposeAsync().AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

### Addressing criticism

1. > **According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter#remarks), *this method is intended for compiler use rather than use directly in code*.**

   Microsoft offers no alternative API that waits synchronously a task, and has the same error-propagating behavior with the [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) operator. So this is what we have to use. Quoting from the article [Task Exception Handling in .NET 4.5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/) by Stephen Toub:

   > However, you may [...] want the original exception propagated unwrapped rather than it being encased in an `AggregateException`. To achieve that, you can target the `Task`’s awaiter directly. When you write `await task;`, the compiler translates that into usage of the `Task.GetAwaiter()` method, which returns an instance that has a `GetResult()` method. When used on a faulted `Task`, `GetResult()` will propagate the original exception (this is how `await task;` gets its behavior). You can thus use `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` if you want to directly invoke this propagation logic.

   The `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is also [recommended by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line#async-main-return-values) for console applications with asynchronous calls in `Main`. Before the introduction of `static async Task Main` entry points in C# 7.1 (August 2017), we were advised to use directly the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` ourselves.
2. > **We've run into deadlocks using this solution. Be warned.**

   The deadlock happens in case a single-threaded synchronization context is installed on the current thread, and the `async` method includes at least one `await` that lacks the [`.ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait) configuration. Under these specific conditions the deadlock is predictable and happens consistently, so you'll be forced to fix it ASAP using one of the available workarounds. It's not an intermittent error that you might miss. The UI will stop responding, and you'll have to kill the process from the Task Manager. The mere fact that the deadlock has such an obtrusive effect, minimizes its risk factor. In other words you won't ship deadlocking code, unless you don't test your application before shipping it.

Comment: We've run into deadlocks using this solution. Be warned.

Comment: [MSDN `Task.GetAwaiter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter.aspx): This method is intended for compiler use rather than for use in application code.

Comment: I still got the error Dialog popup (against my will), with the buttons 'Switch To' or 'Retry'…. however, the call actually executes and does return with a proper response.

Comment: @Oliver, I just came across this article looking for why my application in WebForms was deadlocked when I had the code above. This does indeed cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 33):

You should be able to get this done using delegates, lambda expression

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        label1.Text = "waiting....";

        Task<string> sCode = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            string msg =await GenerateCodeAsync();
            return msg;
        });

        label1.Text += sCode.Result;

    }

    private Task<string> GenerateCodeAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run<string>(() => GenerateCode());
    }

    private string GenerateCode()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return "I m back" ;
    }
```

Comment: This snippet will not compile.  The return type from Task.Run is Task.  See this [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) for full explanation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, yes it returns Task type. Replacing "string sCode" to Task<string> or var sCode should resolve it. Adding a full compile code for ease.

Comment: IMHO, the essence of what makes this more likely to succeed, is using `Task.Run` to wrap the call - thus moving it to the thread pool. However, based on other answer and comments, this does not ensure it will *never* deadlock - it might simply make the deadlock "rare" - thus even harder to track down what is going wrong.

Answer (score 20):

Microsoft Identity has extension methods which call async methods synchronously.
For example there is GenerateUserIdentityAsync() method and equal CreateIdentity()

If you look at UserManagerExtensions.CreateIdentity()
it look like this:

```
 public static ClaimsIdentity CreateIdentity<TUser, TKey>(this UserManager<TUser, TKey> manager, TUser user,
        string authenticationType)
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
        where TUser : class, IUser<TKey>
    {
        if (manager == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("manager");
        }
        return AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, authenticationType));
    }
```

Now lets see what AsyncHelper.RunSync does

```
  public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func)
    {
        var cultureUi = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
        var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        return _myTaskFactory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureUi;
            return func();
        }).Unwrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

So, this is your wrapper for async method.
And please don't read data from Result - it will potentially block your code in ASP.

There is another way - which is suspicious for me, but you can consider it too

```
  Result r = null;

            YourAsyncMethod()
                .ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    r = t.Result;
                })
                .Wait();
```

Comment: What do you consider to be the issue with the second way you have suggested?

Comment: @DavidClarke probably the thread safety issue of accessing a non-volatile variable from multiple threads without a lock.

Answer (score 19):

To prevent deadlocks I always try to use `Task.Run()` when I have to call an async method synchronously that @Heinzi mentions.

However the method has to be modified if the async method uses parameters. For example `Task.Run(GenerateCodeAsync("test")).Result` gives the error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from '`System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>`'
>   to 'System.Action'

This could be called like this instead:

```
string code = Task.Run(() => GenerateCodeAsync("test")).Result;
```

Answer (score 18):

> I need to call this method from a synchronously method.

It's possible with `GenerateCodeAsync().Result` or `GenerateCodeAsync().Wait()`, as the other answer suggests. This would block the current thread until `GenerateCodeAsync` has completed.

However, your question is tagged with [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net), and you also left the comment:

> I was hoping for a simpler solution, thinking that asp.net handled
>   this much easier than writing so many lines of code

My point is, you **should not be blocking** on an asynchronous method in ASP.NET. This will reduce the scalability of your web app, and may create a deadlock (when an `await` continuation inside `GenerateCodeAsync` is posted to `AspNetSynchronizationContext`). Using `Task.Run(...).Result` to offload something to a pool thread and then block will hurt the scalability even more, as it incurs +1 more thread to process a given HTTP request.

ASP.NET has built-in support for asynchronous methods, either through asynchronous controllers (in ASP.NET MVC and Web API) or directly via `AsyncManager` and `PageAsyncTask` in classic ASP.NET. You should use it. For more details, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21793240/1768303).

Comment: I am overwriting `SaveChanges()` method of `DbContext`, and here i am calling the async methods, so unfortunately async controller won't help me in this situation

Comment: @RaraituL, use `SaveChangesAsync` instead.

Comment: i did used `SaveChangesAsync` but i needed to enforce the same methods on `SaveChanges` also

Comment: @RaraituL, in general, you don't mix async and sync code, pick euther model. You can implement both `SaveChangesAsync` and `SaveChanges`, just make sure they don't get called both in the same ASP.NET project.

Comment: Not all `.NET MVC` filters support asynchronous code, for example `IAuthorizationFilter`, so i cannot use `async` all the way

Comment: @Noseratio that is an unrealistic goal. There are too many libraries with asynchronous and synchronous code as well as situations in which using only one model is not possible. MVC ActionFilters don't support asynchronous code, for example.

Comment: [My point is, you should not be blocking on an asynchronous method in ASP.NET] imaginate you must implement some IMyInterface.MySync() method and this method somehow invoked in ASP.NET. You can't change IMyInterface contract.

Comment: @Noserato, the question is about calling  asynchronous method from synchronous. Sometime you can't change API you implementing. Let's say you implementing some synchronous interface from some 3-rd party framework  "A" (you can't rewrite framework to asynchronous manner) but 3rd-party library "B" you are trying to use in your implementation has only asynchronous.  Also resulting product is also library and can be used anywhere including ASP.NET etc.

Answer (score 17):

Most of the answers on this thread are either complex or will result in deadlock.

Following method is simple and it will avoid deadlock because we are waiting for the task to finish and only then getting its result-

```
var task = Task.Run(() => GenerateCodeAsync()); 
task.Wait();
string code = task.Result;
```

Furthermore, here is a reference to MSDN article that talks about exactly same thing-
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/08/28/asp-net-do-not-use-task-result-in-main-context/

Comment: Despite that Microsoft reference, its `Task.Run` that makes this work (when running on ASP.NET context thread). `Wait` is irrelevant - `Result` does the equivalent when task has not completed. See [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35947937/199364).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I don't agree with you. I looked at this reference and the code between the two is not the same. Pulling the .Result directly from the task can randomly result in deadlocks. I know, I've had the issue. Very hard to troubleshoot when it happens.

Comment: I would have to say that this is the most correct solution when you cannot make the calling method async. The best answer is to make the whole flow async.

Comment: @FrankThomas - Looking at the source reference mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35948021/199364, `Task.Wait` tests `IsWaitNotificationEnabledOrNotRanToCompletion`, then calls `InternalWait`. `Future.Result` tests `IsWaitNotificationEnabledOrNotRanToCompletion`, then calls `GetResultCore`, which does `if (!IsCompleted) InternalWait`. I don't see any difference, w.r.t. deadlock potential. Of course its impossible to prove absence of deadlocks, and any change in code changes timing, so its entirely possible to have one approach fail randomly, and the other work .. until it doesn't.

Comment: (I mean its impossible to prove absence, unless the absence is provable by design or by static analysis; my point is that you can't determine that Wait doesn't cause though Result does, given the implementation shown.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for the further explanation. I think it really comes down to trying to make the execution flows that need to be async to be async from beginning to end, whenever possible. Thanks again.

Comment: This approach is still no guarantee for elimination of a deadlock. Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well I was using this approach for years, which also handles and propagates exceptions from the underlying async task.
Which works flawlessly.

```
    private string RunSync()
    {
        var task = Task.Run(async () => await GenerateCodeService.GenerateCodeAsync());
        if (task.IsFaulted && task.Exception != null)
        {
            throw task.Exception;
        }

        return task.Result;
    }
```

But since that Microsoft created this async helper:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/AsyncHelper.cs

Here is also their source:

```
 public static void RunSync(Func<Task> func)
        {
            var cultureUi = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
            var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            _myTaskFactory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureUi;
                return func();
            }).Unwrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Sync Method Generator](https://github.com/zompinc/sync-method-generator) library ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Zomp.SyncMethodGenerator)) to generate a synchronized version of this code.

Use it as follows:

```cs
[Zomp.SyncMethodGenerator.CreateSyncVersion]
public async Task<string> GenerateCodeAsync()
{
    string code = await GenerateCodeService.GenerateCodeAsync();
    return code;
}
```

Which will generate `GenerateCode` method which you can call synchronously.

The source that will be generated is:

```cs
public string GenerateCode()
{
    string code = GenerateCodeService.GenerateCode();
    return code;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about some extension methods that asynchronously await the completion of the asynchronous operation, then set a ManualResetEvent to indicate completion.

NOTE: You can use Task.Run(), however extension methods are a cleaner interface for expressing what you really want.

#### Tests showing how to use the extensions:

```c#
    [TestClass]
    public class TaskExtensionsTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void AsynchronousOperationWithNoResult()
        {
            SampleAsynchronousOperationWithNoResult().AwaitResult();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void AsynchronousOperationWithResult()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(3, SampleAsynchronousOperationWithResult(3).AwaitResult());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
        public void AsynchronousOperationWithNoResultThrows()
        {
            SampleAsynchronousOperationWithNoResultThrows().AwaitResult();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
        public void AsynchronousOperationWithResultThrows()
        {
            SampleAsynchronousOperationWithResultThrows(3).AwaitResult();
        }

        private static async Task SampleAsynchronousOperationWithNoResult()
        {
            await Task.Yield();
        }

        private static async Task<T> SampleAsynchronousOperationWithResult<T>(T result)
        {
            await Task.Yield();
            return result;
        }

        private static async Task SampleAsynchronousOperationWithNoResultThrows()
        {
            await Task.Yield();
            throw new Exception();
        }

        private static async Task<T> SampleAsynchronousOperationWithResultThrows<T>(T result)
        {
            await Task.Yield();
            throw new Exception();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void AsynchronousValueOperationWithNoResult()
        {
            SampleAsynchronousValueOperationWithNoResult().AwaitResult();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void AsynchronousValueOperationWithResult()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(3, SampleAsynchronousValueOperationWithResult(3).AwaitResult());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
        public void AsynchronousValueOperationWithNoResultThrows()
        {
            SampleAsynchronousValueOperationWithNoResultThrows().AwaitResult();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
        public void AsynchronousValueOperationWithResultThrows()
        {
            SampleAsynchronousValueOperationWithResultThrows(3).AwaitResult();
        }

        private static async ValueTask SampleAsynchronousValueOperationWithNoResult()
        {
            await Task.Yield();
        }

        private static async ValueTask<T> SampleAsynchronousValueOperationWithResult<T>(T result)
        {
            await Task.Yield();
            return result;
        }

        private static async ValueTask SampleAsynchronousValueOperationWithNoResultThrows()
        {
            await Task.Yield();
            throw new Exception();
        }

        private static async ValueTask<T> SampleAsynchronousValueOperationWithResultThrows<T>(T result)
        {
            await Task.Yield();
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
```

#### The extensions

```c#
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines extension methods for <see cref="Task"/> and <see cref="ValueTask"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static class TaskExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Synchronously await the results of an asynchronous operation without deadlocking; ignoring cancellation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The <see cref="Task"/> representing the pending operation.
        /// </param>
        public static void AwaitCompletion(this ValueTask task)
        {
            new SynchronousAwaiter(task, true).GetResult();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Synchronously await the results of an asynchronous operation without deadlocking; ignoring cancellation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The <see cref="Task"/> representing the pending operation.
        /// </param>
        public static void AwaitCompletion(this Task task)
        {
            new SynchronousAwaiter(task, true).GetResult();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Synchronously await the results of an asynchronous operation without deadlocking.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The <see cref="Task"/> representing the pending operation.
        /// </param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">
        /// The result type of the operation.
        /// </typeparam>
        /// <returns>
        /// The result of the operation.
        /// </returns>
        public static T AwaitResult<T>(this Task<T> task)
        {
            return new SynchronousAwaiter<T>(task).GetResult();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Synchronously await the results of an asynchronous operation without deadlocking.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The <see cref="Task"/> representing the pending operation.
        /// </param>
        public static void AwaitResult(this Task task)
        {
            new SynchronousAwaiter(task).GetResult();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Synchronously await the results of an asynchronous operation without deadlocking.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The <see cref="ValueTask"/> representing the pending operation.
        /// </param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">
        /// The result type of the operation.
        /// </typeparam>
        /// <returns>
        /// The result of the operation.
        /// </returns>
        public static T AwaitResult<T>(this ValueTask<T> task)
        {
            return new SynchronousAwaiter<T>(task).GetResult();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Synchronously await the results of an asynchronous operation without deadlocking.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The <see cref="ValueTask"/> representing the pending operation.
        /// </param>
        public static void AwaitResult(this ValueTask task)
        {
            new SynchronousAwaiter(task).GetResult();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ignore the <see cref="OperationCanceledException"/> if the operation is cancelled.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The <see cref="Task"/> representing the asynchronous operation whose cancellation is to be ignored.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The <see cref="Task"/> representing the asynchronous operation whose cancellation is ignored.
        /// </returns>
        public static async Task IgnoreCancellationResult(this Task task)
        {
            try
            {
                await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ignore the <see cref="OperationCanceledException"/> if the operation is cancelled.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The <see cref="ValueTask"/> representing the asynchronous operation whose cancellation is to be ignored.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The <see cref="ValueTask"/> representing the asynchronous operation whose cancellation is ignored.
        /// </returns>
        public static async ValueTask IgnoreCancellationResult(this ValueTask task)
        {
            try
            {
                await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ignore the results of an asynchronous operation allowing it to run and die silently in the background.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The <see cref="Task"/> representing the asynchronous operation whose results are to be ignored.
        /// </param>
        public static async void IgnoreResult(this Task task)
        {
            try
            {
                await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch
            {
                // ignore exceptions
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ignore the results of an asynchronous operation allowing it to run and die silently in the background.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The <see cref="ValueTask"/> representing the asynchronous operation whose results are to be ignored.
        /// </param>
        public static async void IgnoreResult(this ValueTask task)
        {
            try
            {
                await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch
            {
                // ignore exceptions
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Internal class for waiting for asynchronous operations that have a result.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">
    /// The result type.
    /// </typeparam>
    public class SynchronousAwaiter<TResult>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The manual reset event signaling completion.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent;

        /// <summary>
        /// The exception thrown by the asynchronous operation.
        /// </summary>
        private Exception exception;

        /// <summary>
        /// The result of the asynchronous operation.
        /// </summary>
        private TResult result;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SynchronousAwaiter{TResult}"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The task representing an asynchronous operation.
        /// </param>
        public SynchronousAwaiter(Task<TResult> task)
        {
            this.manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            this.WaitFor(task);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SynchronousAwaiter{TResult}"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The task representing an asynchronous operation.
        /// </param>
        public SynchronousAwaiter(ValueTask<TResult> task)
        {
            this.manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            this.WaitFor(task);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the operation is complete.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsComplete => this.manualResetEvent.WaitOne(0);

        /// <summary>
        /// Synchronously get the result of an asynchronous operation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The result of the asynchronous operation.
        /// </returns>
        public TResult GetResult()
        {
            this.manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
            return this.exception != null ? throw this.exception : this.result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tries to synchronously get the result of an asynchronous operation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="operationResult">
        /// The result of the operation.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The result of the asynchronous operation.
        /// </returns>
        public bool TryGetResult(out TResult operationResult)
        {
            if (this.IsComplete)
            {
                operationResult = this.exception != null ? throw this.exception : this.result;
                return true;
            }

            operationResult = default;
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Background "thread" which waits for the specified asynchronous operation to complete.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The task.
        /// </param>
        private async void WaitFor(Task<TResult> task)
        {
            try
            {
                this.result = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.exception = exception;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.manualResetEvent.Set();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Background "thread" which waits for the specified asynchronous operation to complete.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The task.
        /// </param>
        private async void WaitFor(ValueTask<TResult> task)
        {
            try
            {
                this.result = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.exception = exception;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.manualResetEvent.Set();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Internal class for  waiting for  asynchronous operations that have no result.
    /// </summary>
    public class SynchronousAwaiter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The manual reset event signaling completion.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        /// <summary>
        /// The exception thrown by the asynchronous operation.
        /// </summary>
        private Exception exception;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SynchronousAwaiter{TResult}"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The task representing an asynchronous operation.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="ignoreCancellation">
        /// Indicates whether to ignore cancellation. Default is false.
        /// </param>
        public SynchronousAwaiter(Task task, bool ignoreCancellation = false)
        {
            this.manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            this.WaitFor(task, ignoreCancellation);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SynchronousAwaiter{TResult}"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The task representing an asynchronous operation.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="ignoreCancellation">
        /// Indicates whether to ignore cancellation. Default is false.
        /// </param>
        public SynchronousAwaiter(ValueTask task, bool ignoreCancellation = false)
        {
            this.manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            this.WaitFor(task, ignoreCancellation);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the operation is complete.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsComplete => this.manualResetEvent.WaitOne(0);

        /// <summary>
        /// Synchronously get the result of an asynchronous operation.
        /// </summary>
        public void GetResult()
        {
            this.manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
            if (this.exception != null)
            {
                throw this.exception;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Background "thread" which waits for the specified asynchronous operation to complete.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        /// The task.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="ignoreCancellation">
        /// Indicates whether to ignore cancellation. Default is false.
        /// </param>
        private async void WaitFor(Task task, bool ignoreCancellation)
        {
            try
            {
                await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.exception = exception;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.manualResetEvent.Set();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Background "thread" which waits for the specified asynchronous operation to complete.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">
        ///     The task.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="ignoreCancellation">
        /// Indicates whether to ignore cancellation. Default is false.
        /// </param>
        private async void WaitFor(ValueTask task, bool ignoreCancellation)
        {
            try
            {
                await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.exception = exception;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.manualResetEvent.Set();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I prefer a non blocking approach:

```
            Dim aw1=GenerateCodeAsync().GetAwaiter()
            While Not aw1.IsCompleted
                Application.DoEvents()
            End While
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

Task has Wait method, Task.Wait(), which waits for the "promise" to resolve and then continues, thus rendering it synchronous. 
example:

```
async Task<String> MyAsyncMethod() { ... }

String mySyncMethod() {

    return MyAsyncMethod().Wait();
}
```

Comment: Kindly elaborate on your Answer. How is it used? How specifically does it help to answer the Question?

Answer (score -3):

If you have an async method called " **RefreshList** " then, you can call that async method from a non-async method like below.

```
Task.Run(async () => { await RefreshList(); });
```