# Understanding the behavior of TaskScheduler.Current

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

Here's a simple WinForms app:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ts = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(new
                {
                    where = "1) before await",
                    currentTs = TaskScheduler.Current,
                    thread = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                    context = SynchronizationContext.Current
                });

                await Task.Yield(); // or await Task.Delay(1)

                Debug.WriteLine(new
                {
                    where = "2) after await",
                    currentTs = TaskScheduler.Current,
                    thread = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                    context = SynchronizationContext.Current
                });

            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, scheduler: ts).Unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

The debug ouput (when the button is clicked):

```
{ where = 1) before await, currentTs = System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler, thread = 9, context = System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext }
{ where = 2) after await, currentTs = System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler, thread = 9, context = System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext }
```

**The question:** Why is `TaskScheduler.Current` changing from `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler` to `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` after `await` here?

This essentially exhibits the behavior `TaskCreationOptions.HideScheduler` for `await` continuation, which is unexpected and undesirable, in my opinion.

This question has been triggered by another question of mine:

[AspNetSynchronizationContext and await continuations in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23062154/1768303).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If there is no actual *task* being executed, then `TaskScheduler.Current` is the same as `TaskScheduler.Default`. In other words, `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` actually acts both as the thread pool task scheduler *and* the value meaning "no current task scheduler".

The first part of the `async` delegate is scheduled explicitly using the `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler`, and runs on the UI thread with both a task scheduler and synchronization context. The task scheduler forwards the delegate to the synchronization context.

When the `await` captures its context, it captures the synchronization context (not the task scheduler), and uses that syncctx to resume. So, the method continuation is posted to that syncctx, which executes it on the UI thread.

When the continuation runs on the UI thread, it behaves very similarly to an event handler; the delegate is executed directly, not wrapped in a task. If you check `TaskScheduler.Current` at the beginning of `button1_Click`, you'll find it is also `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`.

BTW, I recommend you treat this behavior (executing delegates directly, not wrapped in tasks) as an implementation detail.

Comment: This is how I thought it worked but didn't want to comment without a bit more information. +1.

Comment: I see, apparently this is how `TaskAwaiter` works. IMO, the design they've come up with for "flowing" `TaskScheduler.Current` is rather confusing: usually it's not what you'd logically expect it to be.

Comment: Agreed; `TaskScheduler.Current` was designed with dynamic parallelism in mind, so that child tasks inherit the scheduler from their parent tasks. This default behavior is confusing for async tasks, which is why I insist on explicitly specifying the scheduler in every `StartNew` and `ContinueWith`.