# What SynchronizationContext does Task.ContinueWith use?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

Some overloads of [Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) do not take a SynchronizationContext. What SynchronizationContext do they use to schedule the new task?

Comment: You mean TaskScheduler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Some overloads of Task.ContinueWith do not take a SynchronizationContext.

Actually, none of them take a `SynchronizationContext`, but some take a `TaskScheduler`.

> What SynchronizationContext do they use to schedule the new task?

None! By default, the continuation is scheduled by the current scheduler (`TaskScheduler.Current`), which, when not called from a `Task`, is `TaskScheduler.Default`. So the continuation is run on a thread from the thread pool. `ThreadPool` threads don't have an associated synchronization context (unless you explicitly set one).

Comment: *"By default, the continuation is scheduled by the default scheduler (TaskScheduler.Default), so it's run on a thread from the thread pool"* - in fact, it uses `TaskScheduler.Current` by default, rather than `TaskScheduler.Default`.

Answer (score 15):

By default, `ContinueWith` uses `TaskScheduler.Current` for the continuation task, as can be seen in the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#e71924f994d1bb54).

This may be a source of confusion, because the current (ambient) task scheduler can be different from `TaskScheduler.Default`, and it can also be different from the scheduler of the task the continuation is attached to. That's why options like `TaskCreationOptions.HideScheduler` and `TaskContinuationOptions.HideScheduler` were introduced in .NET 4.5.

It is [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23071609/1768303) to always specify the task scheduler explicitly when calling`Task.Factory.StartNew` and `Task.ContinueWith`. Most commonly, you'd specify `TaskScheduler.Default` (for the thread pool task scheduler) or `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`.