# Async-Await no deadlock where a deadlock is expected

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, deadlock, synchronizationcontext

It is known that synchronous waiting on an async method leads to deadlocks
(see, for example [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html))

I have the following code in an event handler for a button-click in a Windows Forms application (i.e. the code is invoked with a UI `SynchronizationContext` installed).

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
Task<HttpResponseMessage> t = client.SendAsync(request);
t.Wait();
var response = t.Result;
```

I fully expected the code to deadlock on clicking the button. However, what I actually see is synchronous waiting - the dialog becomes unresponsive for a while, and then accepts events as usual.
I consistently see deadlocks when I try to synchronously wait on *client* async methods. However, synchronously waiting on *library* async methods like `SendAsync` or `ReadAsByteArrayAsync` seems not to deadlock. Can someone explain this behaviour?

Don't implementations of async methods in .NET libraries use await statements internally, so that the continuations have to be marshalled back to the original SynchronizationContext?

Note:
If I define a client method, say

```
public async Task<byte[]> wrapperMethod()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
}
```

and then say `byte[] byteArray = wrapperMethod().Result;` in the button click handler, I do obtain a deadlock.

Comment: As the accepted answer describes well, there is no deadlock because most Microsoft .NET code does not resume on a captured context. However, be careful depending on this. In particular, I believe `HttpClient` does use `await` (and - incorrectly - resume on a captured context) on some mobile platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Don't implementations of async methods in .NET libraries use await statements internally?

Generally, no. I have yet to see a single implementation in the .NET framework that uses async-await internally. It does use tasks and continuations but not the compiler magic the `async` and `await` keywords bring.

Using async-await is simple as the code looks synchronous but actually runs asynchronously. But that simplicity has a **very small** price in performance.

For most consumers this prices is worth paying, but the framework itself tries to be as performant as possible.

> However, synchronously waiting on library async methods like `SendAsync` or `ReadAsByteArrayAsync` seems not to deadlock.

The deadlock is a result of the default behaviour of await. When you await an uncompleted task the `SynchronizationContext` is captured and when it's completed the continuation is resumed on that `SynchronizationContext` (if it exists). When there's no async, await, captured `SynchronizationContext`, etc. this kind of deadlock can't happen.

`HttpClient.SendAsync` specifically uses `TaskCompletionSource` to return a task without marking the method as async. You can see that in the implementation on github [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L334).

Most task-returning methods added to existing classes for async-await simply build a task using the already existing asynchronous API (i.e. `BeginXXX`/`EndXXX`). For example this is [`TcpClient.ConnectAsync`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs,400):

```
public Task ConnectAsync(IPAddress address, int port)
{
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(BeginConnect, EndConnect, address, port, null);
}
```

When you do use async-await though you avoid the deadlock by using `ConfigureAwait(false)` when you don't need to capture the `SynchronizationContext`. It's recommended that libraries should alway use it unless the context is needed (e.g. a UI library).

Comment: I think the "performance" part is quite misleading in the context of using `async/await` when creating new libraries. Does the BCL use `async/await`? Possibly not. Should *you* use `async/await` when creating new libraries? Definitely. Here's a quote from Microsoft's "TPL Performance Improvements in .NET 4.5": *"Support for the new “await” keyword is built on top of Task continuations, but the await support is
highly optimized and generally much more efficient than an “off the shelf” continuation"*

Comment: Full paper which talks about `Task`'s single-continuation optimisation introduced in .NET 4.5 and implications for `async/await` can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235962.aspx

Comment: Clarification: I'm trying to understand why synchronous waiting on library methods does not seem to deadlock, rather than how to avoid such deadlocks. Any ideas on the first question - why does synchronous waiting on the library methods indicated above not deadlock?

Comment: @Anirudh The deadlock happens because awaiting a task resumes on the captured `SynchronizationContext` (unless specified otherwise). In .NET methods there is no use of await to begin with. There's no option to deadlock. There's no async, await, captured SC, etc...

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy Should **you** use async-await when creating new libraries? probably. Does the .NET team always use async-await when creating new libraries? definitely not.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy though with the addition of `ValueTask` (more on it [on my blog](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2015/11/30/valuetask/)) they would probably be using it more and more as the overhead can be smaller for the right API.

Comment: @i3arnon Thanks for the link to the source. If you happen to know that the BeginXXX/EndXXX methods do not interact with `SynchronizationContext`, I'd be very grateful for some references. Task.ContinueWith does rely on the current SyncContext, for example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350631/what-synchronizationcontext-does-task-continuewith-use. In the meanwhile, I'll try and study the source to try and understand why it does not deadlock.

Comment: @Anirudh no, it doesn't (as the answer you linked to suggests).

Comment: @i3arnon The accepted answer to that question is somewhat misleading. Please see the second answer - it links to [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,e71924f994d1bb54) saying that `TaskScheduler.Current` is used to schedule the continuation

Comment: @ 1. I disagree that it is misleading (the second answer is). 2. `TaskScheduler` is completely different than `SynchronizationContext`. You can create a wrapper of one around the other with `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` but **you** need to do it, it doesn't happen on its own.

Comment: @Anirudh also, if you [search for usages of that method on the .NET core repository you'll find only tests](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=FromCurrentSynchronizationContext&type=Code).

Comment: @Anirudh, you're actually onto something when you blame `SynchronizationContext` rather than `async/await` as ultimately it's the `SynchronizationContext` postback which leads to the deadlock, regardless of the higher-level technology used. I would say, however, that *not* capturing the context as part of async `HttpClient` calls is *common sense*. It's only `Task`s that *must* interact with the thread they're started on, that will deadlock out of the box in your repro, and you won't find very many of those in the .NET base class library (I can only think of async `Dispatcher` calls).

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy The usage of the `SynchronizationContext` happens inside `TaskAwaiter`. Specifically in `Task.SetContinuationForAwait`. That's how it's related to async-await. If you don't await a task that code isn't called. Are there any **other** explicit usages of `SynchronizationContext` in the entire .NET framework? maybe, though probably not a lot.

Comment: This discussion clarified a few things for me. Thanks! @i3arnon, if you substantiate "When there's no async, await, captured SynchronizationContext, etc. this kind of deadlock can't happen." from your answer with references showing that the lower level APIs (beginXXX/endXXX/continueWith) do not capture context, I shall be happy to accept your post as the answer.

Comment: @Anirudh That's the wrong way to think about it. You can see who **does capture** the SC in await, which is the `TaskAwaiter`. `BeingXXX/EndXXX` is a pattern. Everyone can write their own methods and some may capture the SC (though there's no real reason to).

Comment: @i3arnon, thanks for the `ValueTask` info by the way - that's something pretty exciting that I learnt today.

Comment: I think Stream.CopyToAsync to uses await because loops are so hard to build without await. And WebClient captures the SC as an example for that. Horrible API design. No built-in way to tun that feature off.

Comment: @usr [`Stream.CopyToAsyncInternal`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,162)

Answer (score 2):

You won't cause a deadlock by blocking on *most* out-of-the box `Task`-returning .NET calls because they wouldn't internally touch the `SynchronizationContext` that the `Task` was started on unless absolutely necessary (two reasons: performance and avoiding deadlocks).

What this means is that even if standard .NET calls *did* use `async/await` under the covers (i3arnon said they don't - I won't argue as I simply don't know), they would, beyond any doubt, use `ConfigureAwait(false)` unless capturing the context is definitely required.

But that's the .NET framework. As for your own code, you *will* observe a deadlock if you call `wrapperMethod().Wait()` (or `Result`) in your client (provided that you're running with a non-null `SynchronizationContext.Current` - if you're using Windows Forms, this will definitely be the case). Why? Because you're flaunting `async/await` best practices by *not* using `ConfigureAwait(false)` on your awaitables inside `async` methods that do not interact with the UI, causing the state machine to generate continuations that unnecessarily execute on the original `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: They actually use `async/await` quite a bit, e.g.: http://imgur.com/L82cNcr (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,9ca6b2f012ce7587)