# Raising PropertyChanged in asynchronous Task and UI Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

At many blogs, tutorials and MSDN I can read that accessing UI elements from non-UI threads is impossible - ok, I'll get an unauthorized exception. To test it I've written a very simple example:

```
// simple text to which TextBlock.Text is bound
private string sample = "Starting text";
public string Sample
{
    get { return sample; }
    set { sample = value; RaiseProperty("Sample"); }
}

private async void firstButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Job(); // asynchronous heavy job
    commands.Add("Element"); // back on UI thread so this should be ok?
}

private async Task Job()
{
    // I'm not on UI Thread ?
    await Task.Delay(2000); // some other job
    Sample = "Changed";  // not ok as not UI thread?
    commands.Add("Element from async"); // also not ok?
}
```

I've a `Task` which is being run asynchronously. In that `Task` I want to change my property (which will raise `PropertyChanged`) and add element to `ObservableCollection`. As it is run `async`, I shouldn't be able to do that, but I get no exception and the code is working fine. Thus my doubts and misunderstanding:

- why don't I get an exception?
- is it ok to raise `PropertyChanged` in `async` Task?
- is it ok to modify `ObservableCollection` in `async Task`, or should I return `Task<ICollection>` and after obtaining the result modify the `ObservableCollection`- Clear it and Fill it?
- when am I in `Task` on UI thread and when not?
- in the code above in `firstButton_Click` is it ok to manage UI elements after `await`ing the `Task`? Am I always back on UI thread?

To test it more I've put my property change and collection modification in other thread:

```
System.Threading.Timer newThreadTimer = new System.Threading.Timer((x) =>
   {
       Sample = "Changed";  // not UI thread - exception
       commands.Add("Element from async"); // not UI thread - exception
   }, null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

In above code my thinking is ok - just after the first or second line I get an exception. But what with the first code? Is it only a luck that my `Task`was run on UI thread?

I suspect that this is very basic thing and my misunderstanding, but I need some clarification and thus this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When awaiting on a `Task`, the [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) of the current thread is captured (specifically in the case of `Task` by the [`TaskAwaiter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). The continutation is then marshaled back to that `SynchronizationContext` to execute the rest of the method (the part after the `await` keyword).

Lets look at your code example:

```
private async Task Job()
{
    // I'm not on UI Thread ?
    await Task.Delay(2000); // some other job
    Sample = "Changed";  // not ok as not UI thread?
    commands.Add("Element from async"); // also not ok?
}
```

When you `await Task.Delay(2000)`, the compiler implicitly captures the `SynchronizationContext`, which is currently your `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`. When the await returns, the continuation is executed in the same context, since you didn't explicitly tell it not to, which is your UI thread.

If you changed your code to `await Task.Delay(200).ConfigureAwait(false)`, the continuation would not be marshalled back to your current `SynchronizationContext`, and would run a `ThreadPool` thread, causing your UI element update to throw an exception.

In your timer example, the `Elapsed` event is raised via a `ThreadPool` thread, hence why you get an exception that you are trying to update an element which is controlled by a different thread.

Now, let's go over your questions one by one:

> why don't I get exception?

As said, the `await Task.Delay(2000)` executed the Continuation on the UI thread, which made it possible to update your controls.

> is it ok to Raise properties in async Task?

I am not sure what you mean by "Raise properties", but if you mean raise a `INotifyPropertyChanged` event, then yes, it is ok to execute them not in a UI thread context.

> is it ok to modify ObservableCollecition in async Task, or should I
>   return Task and after obtaining the result modify Observable - Clear
>   it and Fill it?

If you have an `async` method and you want to update a UI bound element, make sure you marshal the continuation on the UI thread. If the method is called from the UI thread and you `await` its result, then the continuation will implicitly be ran on your UI thread. In case you want to offload work to a background thread via `Task.Run` and make sure your continuation is ran on the UI, you can capture your `SynchronizationContext` using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` and explicitly pass it the continuation

> when am I in Task on UI thread and when not?

A `Task` is a promise of work that will be done in the future. when you `await` on a `TaskAwaitable` from the UI thread context, then you are still running on the UI thread. You are not in the UI thread if:

1. Your async method is currently executing from a thread different then the UI thread (either a `ThreadPool` thread or a new `Thread`)
2. You offload work to a background ThreadPool thread using `Task.Run`.

> in the code above in firstButton_Click is it ok to manage UI elements
>   after awaiting the Task? Am I always back on UI thread?

You will be back to the UI thread as long as you don't explicitly tell your code not to return to its current context using `ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: I'd +1 this if not this statement: *"The Task Parallel Library uses a `TaskScheduler` to implicitly (or explicitly...) capture the current `SynchronizationContext`..."* This is not quite correct for `await` continuations: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23071609/1768303

Comment: Long answer (thank you for that), but I've some doubts: 1. Look that my Job is run as asynchronous `await Job();` from Click - so captured UI context is before and after not inside? 2. I'm confused with returning from await on the same Thread - for example [I cannot await inside Mutex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23153155/2681948), hence after returning 'the captured context might well mean any thread-pool thread at all'. 3. If is it ok to raise property changed from async Task (on different thread), then why not the Timer?

Comment: @Romasz you are confusing the related by different concepts of `asynchronous`/`synchronous` and `concurrent`. All of the code you have written is SINGLE THREADED. Which means you have no problem. The beginner mistake with `async`/`await` is to think, right...we are asynchronous, that means threads right? Threads mean `concurrent`, and in the past that was the only way to achieve `asynchronous`.

Comment: Also to make things even more fun! I noticed that you are using WPF. Which, although is does not allow you to update UI elements on another thread. WPF automagically marshals data when using the `binding` class.

Comment: @Romasz As @Aron said, you are not marshaling work do a background thread when using the `async` keyword. Meanwhile, your timer is delegating work the a `ThreadPool` thread, which wont let it you update UI elements.

Comment: @Noseratio how would you rephrase that statement that would capture the effect you talked about in your question?

Comment: @Aron Ok that gives me some light, but is async/await always run on the same thread? And so why I cannot use await in `lock` or release `Mutex`, if it's the same thread?

Comment: maybe we should continue this in a chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51870/async-talk

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I'd not mention `TaskScheduler` in the first sentence. The synchronization context capturing behavior you described there is carried by [`TaskAwaiter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter(v=vs.110).aspx), which implements an [awaiter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx?Redirected=true) for C# `async/await` compiler infrastructure.

Comment: @Noseratio Changed it, hope that describes the process correctly this time :)

Comment: In contrast to this answer, I update the UI from `await Task.Run(()=>CurrentProgress = incrementingValue)).ConfigureAwait(false); await Task.Run(()=>Task.Delay(2000)).ConfigureAwait(false);` in a loop, where property CurrentProgress's setter raises PropertyChanged. I am thus inclined to agree with [jnovo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23422983/5569922) instead, explaining that `PropertyChanged` is special in WPF and automatically dispatched to UI thread, regardless of where it was raised.

Answer (score 4):

The `PropertyChanged` event is automatically dispatched to the UI thread by WPF so you can modify properties that raise it from any thread. Before .NET 4.5 this was not the case for `ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged` event and thus, adding or removing elements from a thread other than the UI one, would cause an exception.

Starting in .NET 4.5 `CollectionChanged` is also automatically dispatched to the UI thread so you don't need to worry about that. This being said, you'll still need to access UI elements (such as a button for instance) from the UI thread.

Comment: Correction. WPF always dispatched to the UI thread via bindings. The problem is that it has never supported collections being changed outside of the UI thread. This typically manifests in the `CollectionViewSource` class not supporting blah blah blah.