# await does not resume context after async operation?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I've read [*this question*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23071609/859154)  from Noseratio  which shows a behaviour where `TaskScheduler.Current` is not the *same* after an awaitable has finished its operation.

The answer states that :

> *If there is no actual task* being executed, then `TaskScheduler.Current`
>   is the same as `TaskScheduler.Default`

Which is true . I already saw it  [here](http://everydaylifein.net/netframework/task-parallel-library-taskscheduler-deadlocks-threads.html) :

> - `TaskScheduler.Default`
>
>   - Returns an instance of the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`
> - `TaskScheduler.Current`
>
>   - If called from within an executing task will return the `TaskScheduler` 
>       of the currently executing task
>   - **If called from any other place will return `TaskScheduler.Default`**

But then I thought , If so , Let's *do* create an actual `Task` (and not just `Task.Yield()`) and test it :

```
async void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ts = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show((TaskScheduler.Current == ts).ToString()); //True

           await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.google.com");

        MessageBox.Show((TaskScheduler.Current == ts).ToString());//False

    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None,ts).Unwrap();
}
```

First Messagebox is "True" , second is "False"

**Question:**

As you can see , I did created an actual task.

I can understand why the first MessageBox yield `True`. Thats becuase of the :

> If called from within an executing task will return the TaskScheduler
>   of the currently executing task

And that task does have `ts` which is the sent `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`

But *why*  the context is *not* preserved at the *second* MessageBox ? To me , It wasn't clear from Stephan's answer.

Additional information :

If I write instead (of the second messagebox ) :

```
MessageBox.Show((TaskScheduler.Current == TaskScheduler.Default).ToString());
```

It does yield `true` . But why ?

Comment: Excellent question, but what if `task scheduler != synchronization context`?

Comment: A good case for the hard rule: never assume `TaskScheduler.Current` is what you think it is :) It's only guaranteed to be what you passed to `Factory.StartNew` for the scope of the task action lambda (which is `Func<Task>` in your case and returns when it hits the first `await`). Any other behavior should be treated as implementation details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reasons for confusion are these:

1. The UI doesn't have a "special" `TaskScheduler`. The default case for code running on the UI thread is that `TaskScheduler.Current` stores the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` and `SynchronizationContext.Current` stores `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` (or the relevant one in other UI apps)
2. `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` in `TaskScheduler.Current` doesn't necessarily mean it's the `TaskScheduler` being used to run the current piece of code. It also means `TaskSchdeuler.Current == TaskScheduler.Default` and so **"there is no `TaskScheduler` being used"**.
3. `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` doesn't return an "acutal" `TaskScheduler`. It returns a "proxy" that posts tasks straight to the captured `SynchronizationContext`.

**So if you run your test before starting the task (or in any other place) you'll get the same result** as after the await:

```
MessageBox.Show(TaskScheduler.Current == TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); // False
```

Because `TaskScheduler.Current` is `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` and `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` returns a `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler`.

This is the flow of your example:

- You create a new `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler` from the UI's `SynchronizationContext` (i.e. `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`).
- Schedule the task you create using `Task.Factory.StartNew` on that `TaskScheduler`. Since it's just a "proxy" it posts the delegate to the `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` which invokes it on the UI thread.
- The synchronous part (the part before the first await) of that method is executed on the UI thread, while being associated with the `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler`.
- The method reaches the await and is "suspended" while capturing that `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`.
- When the continuation is resumed after the await it is posted to that `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` and not the `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler` since `SynchronizationContext`s have precedence ([this can be seen in `Task.SetContinuationForAwait`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,2982)). It then **runs regularly on the UI thread, without any "special" `TaskScheduler` so `TaskScheduler.Current == TaskScheduler.Default`**.

So, the created task runs on the proxy `TaskScheduler` which uses the `SynchronizationContext` but the continuation after the await is posted to that `SynchronizationContext` and not the `TaskScheduler`.

Comment: The continuation after the `await` runs on the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`, not the UI.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Why do you say that? I disagree. It's posted to the UI using its `SynchronizationContext`

Comment: Wait, which `await` are you talking about? :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov the one inside the task.

Comment: It is not clear to me why _"UI thread doesn't have a "special" TaskScheduler"_.  there is a context which is the UI thread's context. no?

Comment: @RoyiNamir when you check `TaskScheduler.Current` while running on the UI thread you always get the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`. There's no `WindowsFromTaskScheduler` you need to be on.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov That's already after the continuation was scheduled on the captured `TaskScheduler` and then posted to the `SynchronizationContext`. What you're seeing is the default case for code that runs on the UI thread.

Comment: Then how does the thread pool scheduler know to post continuations onto the UI thread?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov That scheduler is never involved. The scheduler that does that is the `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler` with is the one that's captured before the `await`.

Comment: Then what is this `WinFormsSynchronizationContext` sorcery if it doesn't actually exist? And what kind of name is `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler`? Meaningless

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It does exist, it's just not a `TaskScheduler`. It's a `SynchronizationContext` that executes actions posted to it on the UI thread (where `TaskScheduler.Current` returns the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`).

Comment: This seems correct. WinForms never sets `TaskScheduler.Current`. The TPL does that when it processes the task created with `StartNew`. So if the TPL is not involved, and it ceases to be at the first await, `TaskScheduler.Current` reverts back to the default value.