# Task ContinueWith does not return expected value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library, async-await

This is probably one of those RTFM type questions, however, I cannot for the life of me figure out how chain tasks together in a way that works for Asp.net WebApi.

Specifically, I am looking how to use a `DelegatingHandler` to modify the response after it has been handled by the controller (add an additional header), and I am trying to unit test the `DelegatingHandler` by using a `HttpMessageInvoker` instance.

## First Pattern

```
[TestMethod]
public void FirstTest()
{
    var task = new Task<string>(() => "Foo");

    task.ContinueWith(t => "Bar");

    task.Start();

    Assert.AreEqual("Bar", task.Result);
}
```

This fails on the assert because `task.Result` returns `"Foo"`

## Second Pattern

```
[TestMethod]
public void SecondTest()
{
    var task = new Task<string>(() => "Foo");

    var continueTask = task.ContinueWith(t => "Bar");

    continueTask.Start();

    Assert.AreEqual("Bar", continueTask.Result);
}
```

This fails on `continueTask.Start()` with the exception of **System.InvalidOperationException: Start may not be called on a continuation task.**

## Third Pattern

```
[TestMethod]
public void ThirdTest()
{
    var task = new Task<string>(() => "Foo");

    var continueTask = task.ContinueWith(t => "Bar");

    task.Start();

    Assert.AreEqual("Bar", continueTask.Result);
}
```

This test works the way I expect, however, I am not sure how to get this pattern to work with WebAPI.

## Current Implementation

```
public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var task = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        task.ContinueWith(AddWwwAuthenticateHeaderTask());

        return task;
    }

    private static Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>, HttpResponseMessage> 
        AddWwwAuthenticateHeaderTask()
    {
        return task =>
        {
            var response = task.Result;

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "realm=\"api\""));
            }

            return response;
        };
    }
}
```

However, when I invoke `BasicAuthenticationHandler` from a unit test, my header is not added before the `Assert` happens (if I debug, I notice that the header is added **after** the unit test fails).

```
[TestMethod]
public void should_give_WWWAuthenticate_header_if_authentication_is_missing()
{
    using (var sut = new BasicAuthenticationHandler())
    {
        sut.InnerHandler = new DelegatingHttpMessageHandler(
            () => new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));

        using (var invoker = new HttpMessageInvoker(sut))
        {
            var task = invoker.SendAsync(_requestMessage, CancellationToken.None);

            task.Start();

            Assert.IsTrue(
                task.Result.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Contains(
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "realm=\"api\"")));
        }
    }
}
```

If I change my production code to return the continuation task instead of the result from `base.SendAsync` then I get the 2nd unit test exception about calling `Start` on a continuation task.

I *think* I want to accomplish the third unit test pattern in my production code, however, I have no idea on how to write that.

How do I do what I want (add the header before the assert gets called)?

Comment: Which .NET framework are you using?

Comment: Continuations run even when a task has already completed. You assume that this is not the case leading you to the overly cautious starting behavior. Not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When returning a `Task`, it should always be a `Hot Task`, meaning that the returned task has already been started. Making someone explicitly call `Start()` on a returned task is confusing and violates the guidelines.

To properly see the continuations result, do this:

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(AddWwwAuthenticateHeaderTask()).Unwrap();
}
```

And you should modify `base.SendAsync` to return the already started `Task`

From the [`Task Asynchronous Pattern Guidelines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> All tasks returned from TAP methods must be “hot.” If a TAP method internally uses a Task’s constructor to instantiate the task to be returned, the TAP method must call Start on the Task object prior to returning it. Consumers of a TAP method may safely assume that the returned task is “hot,” and should not attempt to call Start on any Task returned from a TAP method. Calling Start on a “hot” task will result in an InvalidOperationException (this check is handled automatically by the Task class).

Comment: Thank you for the advice on the guidelines, looks like I was working against the grain.

Comment: Turns out my issue was with my `DelegatingHttpMessageHandler` class, I wasn't starting the task that it created.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following. Note `task2.Unwrap()`, I think this part hasn't been addressed by the other answers:

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var task1 = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(t => AddWwwAuthenticateHeaderTask(),
        cancellationToken);

    return task2.Unwrap();
}
```

You need to unwrap the inner task because the type of `task2` is `Task<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>`. This should provide correct continuation semantic and result propagation.

Check Stephen Toub's ["Processing Sequences of Asynchronous Operations with Tasks"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx). This complexity can be avoided with `async`/`await`.

If you can't use `async/await`, you still can further improve this code a bit, to avoid redundant thread switching otherwise caused by `ContinueWith`:

```
var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(
    t => AddWwwAuthenticateHeaderTask(), 
    cancellationToken,
    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
    TaskScheduler.Default);
```

In either case, the continuation will not happen on the original synchronization context (which probably is `AspNetSynhronizationContext`). If you need to stay on the same context, use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` instead of `TaskScheduler.Default`. A word of caution: [this may cause a deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23638886/1768303) in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 3):

> I cannot for the life of me figure out how chain tasks together in a way that works for Asp.net WebApi.

Embrace `async` and `await`. In particular, replace `ContinueWith` with `await` (and do not use the task constructor or `Start`):

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "realm=\"api\""));
    }

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321326.aspx) returns the mapped task so you need to return that:

```
var task = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
return task.ContinueWith(AddWwwAuthenticateHeaderTask());
```