# Should we use ConfigureAwait(false) in libraries that call async callbacks?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, task, synchronizationcontext

There are lots of guidelines for when to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, when using await/async in C#.

It seems the general recommendation is to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in library code, as it rarely depends on the synchronization context.

However, assume we are writing some very generic utility code, which takes a function as input. A simple example could be the following (incomplete) functional combinators, to make simple task-based operations easier:

Map:

```
public static async Task<TResult> Map<T, TResult>(this Task<T> task, Func<T, TResult> mapping)
{
    return mapping(await task);
}
```

FlatMap:

```
public static async Task<TResult> FlatMap<T, TResult>(this Task<T> task, Func<T, Task<TResult>> mapping)
{
    return await mapping(await task);
}
```

The question is, should we use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in this case? I am unsure how the context capture works wrt. closures.

On one hand, if the combinators are used in a functional way, the synchronization context should not be necessary. On the other hand, people might misuse the API, and do context dependent stuff in the provided functions.

One option would be to have separate methods for each scenario (`Map` and `MapWithContextCapture` or something), but it feels ugly.

Another option might be to add the option to map/flatmap from and into a `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<T>`, but as awaitables don't have to implement an interface this would result in a lot of redundant code, and in my opinion be even worse.

Is there a good way to switch the responsibility to the caller, such that the implemented library doesn't need to make any assumptions on whether or not the context is needed in the provided mapping-functions?

Or is it simply a fact, that async methods don't compose too well, without various assumptions?

#### EDIT

Just to clarify a few things:

1. The problem *does* exist. When you execute the "callback" inside the utility function, the addition of `ConfigureAwait(false)` will result in a null sync. context.
2. The main question is how we should tackle the situation. Should we ignore the fact that someone might want to use the sync. context, or is there a good way to shift the responsibility out to the caller, apart from adding some overload, flag or the like?

As a few answers mention, it would be possible to add a bool-flag to the method, but as I see it, this is not too pretty either, as it will have to be propagated all the way through the API's (as there are more "utility" functions, depending on the ones shown above).

Comment: If you want to know what the current context is in the delegate when using `ConfigureAwait(false)` all you had to do was run the code once with a delegate that prints out the current context, or even just code that would crash if the original context wasn't captured.  It'd have taken you far less time than writing this question, given that you already have all of the code written out.

Comment: @Servy Can't argue that. Still, seeing whether or not the problem exists, doesn't necessarily entail that a solution is easily found. And sharing the information doesn't hurt, I hope.

Comment: Rather than saying, "I'm not sure if this problem exists, but if it does, how do I solve it?" spend the 30 seconds to figure out if it exists, and then ask, "how do I solve this problem that I've found?" (or don't ask a question at all because the problem doesn't exist, based on whichever is the case).

Comment: @Servy I certainly have made tests to ensure that there "was a problem". The question is how to handle it, or if we should handle it at all. If the wording doesn't tell that I am interested in some more detailed information, it is a mistake from my side.

Comment: The question, as I read it, seems to be asking if adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` to your method will result in the current context being null or non-null in the callback.  If you know that it's non-null, you should make that clear in the question that you're simply asking about how to best deal with that fact.  Specifically, your question states: `I am unsure how the context capture works wrt. closures.`  This indicates you don't know what will happen.  If you do know, but don't know how to expose a particular set of functionality given that behavior, then that is where you're being unclear.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you say `await task.ConfigureAwait(false)` you transition to the thread-pool causing `mapping` to run under a null context as opposed to running under the previous context. That can cause different behavior. So if the caller wrote:

```
await Map(0, i => { myTextBox.Text = i.ToString(); return 0; }); //contrived...
```

Then this would crash under the following `Map` implementation:

```
var result = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
return await mapper(result);
```

But not here:

```
var result = await task/*.ConfigureAwait(false)*/;
...
```

Even more hideous:

```
var result = await task.ConfigureAwait(new Random().Next() % 2 == 0);
...
```

Flip a coin about the synchronization context! This looks funny but it is not as absurd as it seems. A more realistic example would be:

```
var result =
  someConfigFlag ? await GetSomeValue<T>() :
  await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

So depending on some external state the synchronization context that the rest of the method runs under can change.

This also can happen with very simple code such as:

```
await someTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

If `someTask` is already completed at the point of awaiting it there will be no switch of context (this is good for performance reasons). If a switch is necessary then the rest of the method will resume on the thread pool.

This non-determinism a weakness of the design of `await`. It's a trade-off in the name of performance.

The most vexing issue here is that when calling the API is is not clear what happens. This is confusing and causes bugs.

**What to do?**

**Alternative 1:** You can argue that it is best to ensure deterministic behavior by always using `task.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

The lambda must make sure that it runs under the right context:

```
var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext;
Map(..., async x => await Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => { /*access UI*/ },
        CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler));
```

It's probably best to hide some of this in a utility method.

**Alternative 2:** You can also argue that the `Map` function should be agnostic to the synchronization context. It should just leave it alone. The context will then flow into the lambda. Of course, the mere presence of a synchronization context might alter the behavior of `Map` (not in this particular case but in general). So `Map` has to be designed to handle that.

**Alternative 3:** You can inject a boolean parameter into `Map` that specifies whether to flow the context or not. That would make the behavior explicit. This is sound API design but it clutters the API. It seems inappropriate to concern a basic API such as `Map` with synchronization context issues.

**Which route to take?** I think it depends on the concrete case. For example, if `Map` is a UI helper function it makes sense to flow the context. If it is a library function (such as a retry helper) I'm not sure. I can see all alternatives make sense. Normally, it is recommended to apply `ConfigureAwait(false)` in *all* library code. Should we make an exception in those cases where we call user callbacks? What if we have already left the right context e.g.:

```
void LibraryFunctionAsync(Func<Task> callback)
{
    await SomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); //Drops the context (non-deterministically)
    await callback(); //Cannot flow context.
}
```

So unfortunately, there is no easy answer.

Comment: Usr, in the light of [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28410046/1768303), do you think it might be a good idea to not use `ConfigureAwait` at all (especially if the code runs in ASP.NET) and leave it up to the client (the top-level caller) to use `Task.Run`or something like `WithNoContext` to control the context for the whole chain of async calls?

Comment: @Noseratio that would make Map a more special-purpose function because it now deals with the synccontext in addition to doing its business. If that's architecturally OK that is a valid route. I don't think that's pretty, though. I hate hidden dependencies on hidden state. The presence of a synccontext is not transparent. It changes semantics meaningfully.

Comment: Usr, I see your point and I tend to agree, although one might argue that general-purpose libraries are usually context-agnostic, i.e., they shouldn't depend on or alter the current context.

Comment: @noseratio My thinking on this has evolved. I tend to agree with you now. You might read the edit if you care.

Comment: A nice amendment, @usr! I myself stopped using `ConfigureAwait(false)` in the libraries. Then if I call an API and I feel it might be performance-sensitive to the context, I just wrap it with `Task.Run`. It seems though, these days no one cares about how to squeeze out an extra bit of performance with tweaks like `ConfigureAwait`. People just use JavaScript for both front-end and back-end, and nobody seems to care about [how it works behind the scene](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53146565/1768303). Apparently, it's much easier/cheaper just to throw more virtualized hardware into it if needed.

Answer (score 9):

> The question is, should we use ConfigureAwait(false) in this case?

Yes, you should. If the inner `Task` being awaited is context aware and does use a given synchronization context, it would still be able to capture it even if whoever is invoking it is using `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Don't forget that when disregarding the context, you're doing so in the higher level call, **not inside the provided delegate.** The delegate being executed inside the `Task`, if needed, will need to be context aware.

You, the invoker, have no interest in the context, so it's absolutely fine to invoke it with `ConfigureAwait(false)`. This effectively does what you want, it leaves the choice of whether the internal delegate will include the sync context up to the caller of your `Map` method.

**Edit:**

The important thing to note is that once you use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, any method execution after that would be on on an arbitrary threadpool thread.

A good idea suggested by @i3arnon would be to accept an optional `bool` flag indicating whether context is needed or not. Although a bit ugly, would be a nice work around.

Comment: The lambda will capture the context at the point where it is called. At that point the sync context might be null already.

Comment: But the user will be providing him that delegate. If he needs to context, he should capture it.

Comment: I must have misunderstood you.

Comment: @usr If you call `Map` and provide it with a task returning delegate that is context aware, it would *still be* context aware even if I wrap it with `await providedTask.ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov But the point is that this forces the delegate to be explicitly aware of the context that it wishes to use upon creation of the delegate, rather than relying on the current context when invoked.  Since the former requires explicit work, and the latter is implicit in the workings of `await`, it's very much reasonable to go out of one's way to support the latter.  Just because you can make it work doesn't mean *you should have to*.  It removes much of the utility of such a method.

Comment: It turns out I even misunderstood the question. I thought he wants to call ConfigureAwait(false) on *everything else* in his util function. That would transition to the thread-pool (potentially non-deterministically) and call the delegate under different contexts. That would be a good question. Now calling ConfigureAwait on the resulting task is a much more mundane question...

Comment: @usr You didn't get me wrong it seems. I am talking about calling ConfigureAwait(false) inside the utility function itself, and not on the result of a call to the utility function.

Comment: @nilu yes. When you say `await task.CA(false)` you transition to the thread-pool causing `mapping` to run under a null context as opposed to running under the previous context. Is that the question?

Comment: @usr You're causing *the continuation* to execute on a threadpool thread.

Comment: @usr Yes, it is exactly my question in some sense. The more interesting aspect, of course, is if there is a good way to push the responsibility to the caller in some fancy way.

Comment: @nilu My response talks about calling CA *inside* tge utility function, not inside the delegate provided to the `Task`

Comment: No, the delegate itself runs on the TP. Make the delegate `async _ => { cw(threadid); }` to see that.

Comment: Which delegate? The one encapsulated inside the task?

Comment: @nilu You can accept a SynchronizationContext in the method and post to it when it isn't null. This can be an optional parameter with a `null` default value. Or just a boolean whether to use ConfigureAwait.

Answer (score 6):

I think the real issue here comes from the fact that you are adding operations to `Task` while you actually operate on the result of it.

There's no real reason to duplicate these operations for the task as a container instead of keeping them on the task result.

That way you don't need to decide how to `await` this task in a utility method as that decision stays in the consumer code.

If `Map` is instead implemented as follows:

```
public static TResult Map<T, TResult>(this T value, Func<T, TResult> mapping)
{
    return mapping(value);
}
```

You can easily use it with or without `Task.ConfigureAwait` accordingly:

```
var result = await task.ConfigureAwait(false)
var mapped = result.Map(result => Foo(result));
```

`Map` here is just an example. The point is what are you manipulating here. If you are manipulating the task, you shouldn't `await` it and pass the result to a consumer delegate, you can simply add some `async` logic and your caller can choose whether to use `Task.ConfigureAwait` or not. If you are operating on the result you don't have a task to worry about.

You can pass a boolean to each of these methods to signify whether you want to continue on the captured context or not (or even more robustly pass an options `enum` flags to support other `await` configurations). But that violates separation of concerns, as this doesn't have anything to do with `Map` (or its equivalent).

Comment: But in that case the method wouldn't make any sense - it would just be a more verbose way of calling the mapping directly. Although the example is simple, I am talking about a rather fundamental way of abstracting over a task.

Comment: With all due respect this Map method is useless. It could simply be `Foo(await task)`.

Comment: That would be useful when the method has a single line of execution. If he needs to operate on the returned `Task`, he'll be forced to `await`

Comment: @nilu there's a difference whether you are operating on the task or on the result. You can do whatever you want on the result without worrying (map is just an example). When you're operating on the task you probably shouldn't accept consumer delegates.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It's useless in the example itself. That's the point. It shouldn't be defined on a Task.

Comment: @i3arnon I am not arguing whether or not the code is useful or not. The example is simple, yes, but being able to compose async methods in a functional way certainly is interesting to me.

Comment: @nilu I'm not talking about the specific example. I'm talking about separation of concerns. Your utility method should either be a "logic" method on that value, or an `async` utility on the `Task`. You're troubles come from mixing the two together.

Comment: @nilu you can pass a boolean every time to specify how the `await` should behave (or even more robust, an enum of options) but you don't need to do that to begin with.

Comment: I think this answer misses the point by saying `Map` is defined wrong. It's a totally contrived example. Of course you wouldn't design the signature like this if the method's only purpose is to act on the result. A more realistic example of passing an async delegate is when you want deferred/lazy execution. i.e. caller defines "what", library method defines "when" or even "if" (and perhaps does something after). That can't be refactored to this. I interpret the question as: "_assuming we need to await the delegate's Task in the library method_, should we use `ConfigureAwait(false)`?"

Comment: @ToddMenier Using `ConfigureAwait` on the delegate's task has no effect on the code inside the delegate. It only affects the library's code **after** that await.

The issue with the design in question is that it requires awaiting both the "extended" task **and** the async delegate because using `ConfigureAwait` on the task affects the delegate. That basically makes this method like `ContinueWith` and so to be done correctly requires all of its expressiveness.

Comment: @i3arnon That makes perfect sense. After a bit of head-scratching (and rereading of the question), I clearly misinterpreted it.