# Constructor of a custom promise class is called twice (extending standard Promise)

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, promise, async-await

I'm playing with [Promise Extensions for JavaScript (prex)](https://github.com/rbuckton/prex#readme) and I want to extend the standard [Promise class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with cancellation support using [prex.CancellationToken](https://github.com/rbuckton/prex/blob/master/docs/cancellation.md#class-cancellationtoken), [complete code here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/207116/35474).

Unexpectedly, I'm seeing the constructor of my custom class `CancellablePromise` being called twice. To simplify things, I've now stripped down all the cancellation logic and left just a bare minimum required to repro the issue:

```js
class CancellablePromise extends Promise {
  constructor(executor) {
    console.log("CancellablePromise::constructor");
    super(executor);
  }
}

function delayWithCancellation(timeoutMs, token) {
  // TODO: we've stripped all cancellation logic for now
  console.log("delayWithCancellation");
  return new CancellablePromise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, timeoutMs);
  }, token);
}

async function main() {
  await delayWithCancellation(2000, null);
  console.log("successfully delayed.");
}

main().catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Running it with `node simple-test.js`, I'm getting this:

```
delayWithCancellation
CancellablePromise::constructor
CancellablePromise::constructor
successfully delayed.
```

**Why are there two invocations of `CancellablePromise::constructor`?**

I tried setting breakpoints with VSCode. The stack trace for the second hit shows it's called from `runMicrotasks`, which itself is called from `_tickCallback` somewhere inside Node.

**Updated**, Google now have ["await under the hood"](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async#await-under-the-hood) blog post which is a good read to understand this behavior and some other async/await implementation specifics in V8.

**Updated**, as I keep coming back to this, adding `static get [Symbol.species]() { return Promise; }` to the `CancellablePromise` class [solves the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60328122/1768303).

Comment: after `console.log("CancellablePromise::constructor");` add `console.log(executor+'')` - and all will be revealed

Comment: @Bravo, it's a different version of `executor`, not mine: `function () { [native code] }`

Comment: what does `await` do?

Comment: @Bravo thanks for pointing that out. I suspect it will be the implicit `Promise.resolve()` call made by `await` but will need to check it out before getting back.

Comment: it's more an implicit `.then` - but the internals of `async`/`await` are not important - remove the `await` **(but keep the `async`)** and while now the code isn't behaving correctly, you'll see only a single `CancellablePromise::constructor` call

Comment: @Bravo, indeed looks like implicit `then` it is. I wonder if it would do the same behind the scene if I didn't subclass `Promise`.

Comment: yes, because `.then` returns a new Promise - I guess subclassing Promise means it returns a new subclassed Promise :p

Comment: @Bravo, makes sense. To handle `await`, I imagine they have to attach via `then` to support all the 3rd party `Promise` implementations like Bluebird. Feel free to post it as answer.

Comment: It's probably more useful to use something like `console.trace("Trace")` in the constructor to see the stack when it's called. You will see the first call made in `main`, but the next in `Promise.then()` suggesting that await is calling the constructor.

Comment: @noseratio - I don't really have anything I would class as an *answer*. There are far more knowledgeable people on stackoverflow when it comes to the inner workings of Promises that will hopefully come across this question and explain it in a meaningful way (rather than my  *hey, chuck a console.log here, remove this, and see how this happens*) it's not really a definitive answer in my opinion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First Update:*

I first thought `.catch( callback)` after 'main' would return a new, pending promise of the extended Promise class, but this is incorrect - calling an async function returns a `Promise` promise.

Cutting the code down further, to only produce a pending promise:

```js
class CancellablePromise extends Promise {
  constructor(executor) {
    console.log("CancellablePromise::constructor");
    super(executor);
  }
}

async function test() {
   await new CancellablePromise( ()=>null);
}
test();
```

shows the extended constructor being called twice in Firefox, Chrome and Node.

Now `await` calls `Promise.resolve` on its operand. (Edit: or it probably did in early JS engine's versions of async/await not strictly implemented to standard)

If the operand is a promise whose constructor is Promise, `Promise.resolve` returns the operand unchanged.

If the operand is a thenable whose constructor is not `Promise`, `Promise.resolve` calls the operand's then method with both onfulfilled and onRejected handlers so as to be notified of the operand's settled state. The promise created and returned by this call to `then`  is of the extended class, and accounts for the second call to CancellablePromise.prototype.constructor.

#### Supporting evidence

1. `new CancellablePromise().constructor` is `CancellablePromise`

```js
class CancellablePromise extends Promise {
  constructor(executor) {
    super(executor);
  }
}

console.log ( new CancellablePromise( ()=>null).constructor.name);
```

2. Changing `CancellablePromise.prototype.constructor` to `Promise` for testing purposes causes only one call to `CancellablePromise` (because `await` is fooled into returning its operand) :

```js
class CancellablePromise extends Promise {
  constructor(executor) {
    console.log("CancellablePromise::constructor");
    super(executor);
  }
}
CancellablePromise.prototype.constructor = Promise; // TESTING ONLY

async function test() {
   await new CancellablePromise( ()=>null);
}
test();
```

---

*Second Update* (with huge thanks to links provided by the OP)

**Conforming Implementations**

Per the  [`await` specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#await)

`await` creates an anonymous, intermediate **Promise** promise with onFulilled and onRejected handlers to either 
resume execution after the `await` operator or throw an error from it, depending on which settled state the intermediate promise achieves.

It (`await`) also calls `then` on the operand promise to fulfill or reject the intermediate promise. This particular `then` call returns a promise of class `operandPromise.constructor`. Although the `then` returned promise is never used, logging within an extended class constructor reveals the call.

If the `constructor` value of an extended promise is changed back to `Promise` for experimental purposes, the above `then` call will *silently* return a Promise class promise.

---

**Appendix: Decyphering the [`await` specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#await)**

> 1. Let asyncContext be the running execution context.
> 2. Let promiseCapability be ! NewPromiseCapability(%Promise%).

Creates a new jQuery-like deferred object with `promise`, `resolve` and `reject` properties, calling it a "PromiseCapability Record" instead. The deferred's `promise`  object is of the (global) base **Promise** constructor class.

> 3. Perform ! Call(promiseCapability.[[Resolve]], undefined, « promise »).

Resolve the deferred promise with the right operand of `await`. The resolution process either calls the `then` method of the operand if it is a "thenable", or fulfills the deferred promise if the operand is some other, non-promise, value.

> 4. Let stepsFulfilled be the algorithm steps defined in Await Fulfilled Functions.
> 5. Let onFulfilled be CreateBuiltinFunction(stepsFulfilled, « [[AsyncContext]] »).
> 6. Set onFulfilled.[[AsyncContext]] to asyncContext.

Create an onfulfilled handler to resume the `await` operation, inside the `async` function it was called in, by returning the fulfilled value of the operand passed as argument to the handler.

> 7. Let stepsRejected be the algorithm steps defined in Await Rejected Functions.
> 8. Let onRejected be CreateBuiltinFunction(stepsRejected, « [[AsyncContext]] »).
> 9. Set onRejected.[[AsyncContext]] to asyncContext.

Create an onrejected handler to resume the `await` operation, inside the `async` function it was called in, by throwing a promise rejection reason passed to the handler as its argument.

> 10. Perform ! PerformPromiseThen(promiseCapability.[[Promise]], onFulfilled, onRejected).

Call `then` on the deferred promise with these two handlers so that `await` can respond to its operand being settled.

This call using three parameters is an optimisation that effectively means `then` has been called internally and won't be creating or returning a promise from the call. Hence settlement of the deferred will dispatch calling one of its settlement handlers to the promise job queue for execution, but has no additional side effects.

> 11. Remove asyncContext from the execution context stack and restore the execution context that is at the top of the execution context stack as the running execution context.
> 12. Set the code evaluation state of asyncContext such that when evaluation is resumed with a Completion completion, the following steps of the algorithm that invoked Await will be performed, with completion available.

Store where to resume after a successful `await` and return to the event loop or micro task queue manager.

Comment: it's not the `.catch` - remove it, and you still call constructor twice

Comment: Spot on! How interesting.. I'd expect it to create a standard `Promise` rather than another instance of my `CancellablePromise`.

Comment: @noseratio why? It would render your custom class kinda worthless if it did... if you really want it to return normal Promises [you can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species)

Comment: it's still not correct - remove `.catch` - you wont believe what happens next

Comment: @JaredSmith I agree, but @Bravo is also right. I removed `catch` and I suspect Node is still creating another promise somehow to chain to mine.

Comment: @Bravo thanks for pointing that out. I will look into the use of `Promise,resolvel` by `await`and get back.

Comment: @traktor53, so now we know, while `catch` does create a new `Promise`, it is not an instance of `CancellablePromise` here. If `main` returned `CancellablePromise`, then yes, it would be.

Comment: @traktor53, *Now await calls Promise.resolve on its operand.* - did you rather mean *Now await calls **Promise.then** on its operand.*?

Comment: @noseratio no I did not. `await` is always asynchronous and calls `Promise resolve` to convert non-promise operands into Promise promises. This conversion is applied to extended Promise class instances as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183099/discussion-between-traktor53-and-noseratio).

Comment: It appears you're right, I've found this [TC39's `Async Functions`](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait):  `Promise.resolve(next.value).then(function(v) ...` I let this q/a hang out for a while to get more attention. I hope some of V8 or TC39 team members might come across this. Like @RonBuckton who seems to be deeply involved in this stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @noseratio That link's gold. No so good the explanation - deconstructing the standard worked better for me to show why `await` uses two turns in the Promise Job Queue. Thanks!