# Is it advantageous to use ConfigureAwait(false) in a library that directly returns a Task from a call to another library?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient

Follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32542861/62600). I have a library with many async methods that thinly wrap [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx). Effectively they just do some setup and directly return the `Task` returned from the `HttpClient` call:

```
public Task DoThingAsyc() {
    // do some setup
    return httpClient.DoThingAsync();
}
```

I'm pondering whether to add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to these calls. The prevailing wisdom seems to be "yes, always do that in libraries." But in this case, it would introduce some (perhaps negligible) overhead, because `ConfigureAwait` returns a `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable` which would need to be wrapped back into a `Task` in order to not change the method signature. Certainly not hard to code:

```
public async Task DoThingAsyc() {
    // do some setup
    return await httpClient.DoThingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

My question is, will the efficiency benefits of `ConfigureAwait(false)` likely outweigh the extra overhead introduced in this case? What example above would be considered the better practice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, don't do this.

Since you're not using `await`, you're not supposed to configure for it in advance. It's the responsibility of the caller of your library to do the `ConfigureAwait` call. And the caller may well want to call `ConfigureAwait(true)` instead of `ConfigureAwait(false)` - you don't know that.

Calling `ConfigureAwait(false)` in library code is best practice only when *you* await on it in the library.

In *most cases*, code like this:

```
async Task<Something> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    return await DoSomethingElseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Task<Something> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    return DoSomethingElseAsync();
}
```

***if*** `DoSomethingElseAsync` respects the `Task` contract (for instance, if it returns a failed `Task` instead of throwing exceptions).

Creating an additional state machine for that is just adding one layer of wrapping code with no added value - it is better to simply return the `Task` directly.

In other words: you get *no efficiency benefit whatsoever* from doing this, quite the contrary.

Comment: That's the case - *he* awaits on the `ConfigureAwait` inside the library.

Comment: @GSerg I'll expand my answer

Comment: Thanks! I think these are equally good answers, but gotta give it to the guy who chimed in first.

Answer (score 7):

No, `ConfigureAwait` as its name suggests, configures the `await`. If you don't need to `await` then you don't need to configure it.

There's no added value in adding async-await just to use `ConfigureAwait` as it only affects your method and not the calling method. If the caller needs to use `ConfigureAwait` they will do so themselves.

Having an async method instead of a simple `Task`-returning method is a valid choice for many reasons (e.g. exception handling), and it will require using `ConfigureAwait` but `ConfigureAwait` is not a good reason for doing that by itself.

Comment: Funny, I've been pondering this for a while and yet it never occurred to me until you guys pointed it out - "there is no `await`, so what the hell are you configuring?" Benefit of a fresh set of eyes!