# Run async task continuation on native function callback thread

Tags: c#, windows, async-await, pinvoke

I have a C function `FsReadStream` that does some asynchronous work and takes a callback. When done, it calls the callback using the [QueueUserWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684957(v=vs.85).aspx) windows function.

I am trying to call this function from managed code (c#) using the async/await pattern. So I do the following

1. Construct a `Task` object passing the constructor a lambda that returns the result.
2. Construct a callback that runs this task using the `RunSynchronously` method
3. Call the asynchronous native function, passing in the callback
4. Return the task object to the caller

My code looks something like this

```
/// Reads into the buffer as many bytes as the buffer size
public Task<ReadResult> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer)
{
    GCHandle pinnedBuffer = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    IntPtr bytesToRead = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(long));
    Marshal.WriteInt64(bytesToRead, buffer.Length);

    FsAsyncInfo asyncInfo = new FsAsyncInfo();
    ReadResult readResult = new ReadResult();

    Task<ReadResult> readCompletionTask = new Task<ReadResult>(() => { return readResult; });
    TaskScheduler scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    asyncInfo.Callback = (int status) =>
    {
        readResult.ErrorCode = status;
        readResult.BytesRead = (int)Marshal.ReadInt64(bytesToRead);
        readCompletionTask.RunSynchronously(scheduler);
        pinnedBuffer.Free();
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(bytesToRead);
    };

    // Call asynchronous native method    
    NativeMethods.FsReadStream(
                    pinnedBuffer.AddrOfPinnedObject(),
                    bytesToRead,
                    ref asyncInfo);

    return readCompletionTask;
}
```

and I call it like this

```
ReadResult readResult = await ReadAsync(data);
```

I have two questions

1. How to make the code that runs after the call to `await ReadAsync` run on the same thread as the callback? Currently, I see it runs on a different thread even though I am calling `readCompletionTask.RunSynchronously`. I am running this code under ASP.NET and IIS.
2. Does the native `QueueUserWorkItem` function use the same threadpool as the managed [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct(v=vs.110).aspx) method? My opinion was that it should, and therefore it should be possible for the managed `TaskScheduler` to schedule tasks on the native callback thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to make the code that runs after the call to await ReadAsync run on the same thread as the callback?

This is not possible in a reliable way. `ExecuteSynchronously` is not a guarantee. `RunSynchronously` does not guarantee it either. You can of course pass in a callback and call that callback synchronously.

Also, what does `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` return? My spider sense is telling me that this is based on a misunderstanding...

> Does the native QueueUserWorkItem function use the same threadpool as the managed ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method?

I don't think so and even if this was the case you could not target a particular thread. You only could target a particular pool.

Why do you need to execute on the same thread? Usually, people who ask about that really do want and need something else.

---

Your way to create and return a task is very odd. Why are you not using the standard pattern based on `TaskCompletionSource`?

---

I think you have a GC hole because nothing keeps `asyncInfo.Callback` alive. It can be collected away while the native call is in progress. Use `GC.KeepAlive` in the callback.

Comment: I used the `Task` ctor instead of `TaskCompletionSource` because that allowed me to specify the scheduler when running the task. The scheduler is of type `System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler`. Thanks for pointing out the GC hole.

Comment: Trying to execute the code after await on the callback thread so as to avoid context switching between threads

Comment: You can specify the scheduler for the task but not for the continuations. There is no point in running `return readResult;` on any particular thread.; `avoid context switching` OK, so specify `ExecuteSynchronously` for the continuations. This works 99% of the time. Then, throw out the funky TCS emulation and use TCS. Does this answer the question?

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies a bit. I am still looking for a way to run the continuation on the callback thread, even if that works only 99% of the time.

Comment: Use TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously. It does just that. Any problems doing that?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use the `Task` constructor in modern code. At all. Ever. There is no use case for it.

In this case, you should use `TaskCompletionSource<T>`.

> How to make the code that runs after the call to await ReadAsync run on the same thread as the callback?

You can't guarantee it; `await` just doesn't work that way. If the code absolutely *must* execute on the same thread, then it should be called directly from the callback.

However, if it's just *preferred* to execute on the same thread, then you don't have to do anything special; `await` already uses the `ExecuteSynchronously` flag:

```
public Task<ReadResult> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ReadResult>();
  GCHandle pinnedBuffer = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);

  IntPtr bytesToRead = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(long));
  Marshal.WriteInt64(bytesToRead, buffer.Length);

  FsAsyncInfo asyncInfo = new FsAsyncInfo();
  asyncInfo.Callback = (int status) =>
  {
    tcs.TrySetResult(new ReadResult
    {
      ErrorCode = status;
      BytesRead = (int)Marshal.ReadInt64(bytesToRead);
    });
    pinnedBuffer.Free();
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(bytesToRead);
  };

  NativeMethods.FsReadStream(pinnedBuffer.AddrOfPinnedObject(), bytesToRead, ref asyncInfo);

  return tcs.Task;
}
```

> Does the native QueueUserWorkItem function use the same threadpool as the managed ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method?

No. Those are two completely different thread pools.

Comment: Interesting. Is there an msdn that discourages the use of the `Task` ctor. You are essentially claiming both the `Task` ctor and `Task.RunSynchronously` methods are deprecated.

Comment: @tcb: No. MSDN (and most Microsoft documentation) is descriptive, not prescriptive. I summarize my arguments on my blog about [why the `Task` constructor is useless](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html) and [why `RunSynchronously` is useless](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/02/a-tour-of-task-part-8-starting.html).

Comment: Worth noting though that under ASP.NET and IIS (which @tcb specified as runtime environment) `await ReadAsync(data)` won't continue on the same thread, unless it's `await ReadAsync(data).ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: @Noseratio: I believe it will continue on the same thread. I haven't tested it, though.

Comment: @StephenCleary, it won't unfortunately, at least not in the current implementation of `AspNetSynchronizationContext`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23062154/1768303. I still don't know why they took that route.