# How to use UserManager synchronously?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

In one of my `IDatabaseInitializer` in `Seed` method given my `DbContext` I insert initial data to DB. Among other things there are some users to be initialized. But as far as I use `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore` with `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager` which has *only* asynchronous methods it makes `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` as follows:

```
private static void CreateUser(DbContext context, string[] roles, string userName, string userEmail) {

    // given context is 
    var user = new ApplicationUser { /* ... fields init */  };

    var userStoreAdapter = new ApplicationUserRepository(context);
    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStoreAdapter);

    // pass the creation to manager by calling it synchronously. See UserManagerExtensions
    manager.Create(user, Domain.Constants.DefaultPassword);
    manager.AddToRoles(user.Id, roles);

    context.SaveChanges(); // throws DbUpdateConcurrencyException. See another approach below.
}
```

So the question is if there is a way to use `UserManager` with `DbContext` without concurrency issues?

I've tried the following approach taken from [Optimistic Concurrency Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904) but that does not create users:

```
bool isSaved = true;
do
{
    try
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
        isSaved = true;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        foreach (var entry in ex.Entries)
        {
            entry.Reload();
        }
        isSaved = false;
    }
} while (!isSaved);
```

Comment: I think your question breaks down to, "how do I call an async method from a sync method?" If so, this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628087/calling-async-method-synchronously

Comment: @NathanA `Task` always runs in another thread, right? So `UserManager` updates DB while the given `DbContext` is not aware of it. And it breaks with the concurrency exception as above. So could I run it in the current thread? The post does not look to help. [`AsyncHelper`](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/AsyncHelper.cs) which is called by the extension methods for `UserManager` does the similar thing.

Comment: I believe I have the same issue. In my situation the client kicks off a lengthy database script and the server's response is a 200 OK. But after the lengthy process completes I attempt to run the _RoleManager.CreateAsync and nothing happens. Did you find a work around? @Artyom?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I run an async Task<T> method synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously)

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = Task.Run(() => {
   /*whatever you want here*/
}).Result;

// Do whatever u want with the result after
```

Answer (score -1):

To use the **UserManager** synchronously you need to call the *.GetAwaiter().GetResult()* extension methods from System.Threading.Tasks. For example to get the current user synchronously using the user manager:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
var currentUser = _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

These two extension methods from the System.Threading.Tasks namespace gets the awaiter for the task *GetUsersAsync()* and gets the result.

Comment: `async` keyword doesn't make your code running in parallel. All it does is relieves the thread while waiting for I/O operation to complete. So it is not the case here

Comment: If you check the CreateUser method above it is a synchronous method, and the user wants to use UserManager in a synchronous method not to run the code parallel if that is the case they did not mention it in the question

Comment: There are no async method calls in OP's code. They don't describe their problem correctly.

Comment: It worked for me to convert User object, thence the upvote

Comment: GetAwaiter().GetResult() didn't work for me. Also _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result didn't work for me.