# How to call async method from other class file

Tags: c#, uwp

Need help.. This is my first application ever. I'm trying to populate GridView with JSON data. code below works, but now I'm trying to move the `async private void haePostimerkitPilvesta()` and `public static string ReadStreamAsString(Stream input)`  method code blocks from `MainPage.xaml.cs` to other .cs file with no luck.. How should I write the code so that I can call it correctly? without async method I am able to do the same, but then the code does not work.

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        haePostimerkitPilvesta();
    }

    async private void haePostimerkitPilvesta()
    {

        Uri address = new Uri("xxx.json"); //public link of our file
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
        WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        string content = ReadStreamAsString(stream);
        GridViewPostimerkit.ItemsSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content, typeof(List<Postimerkit>));

    }

    public static string ReadStreamAsString(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray(), 0, ms.ToArray().Count());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling async method synchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628087/calling-async-method-synchronously)

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628087/calling-async-method-synchronously

Comment: Are you changing the private method to public when you move it?

Comment: You say "no luck". Is that a runtime error? Is it throwing a `NoLuckException` at runtime? Or is it a compiler error, `No Luck in line 115`? Do you mean you were unable to paste the text of the methods into the new file, due to some indefinable probabilistic misadventure? Or do you just have a pervasive sense of looming misfortune? Please be specific about where your luck is running out, and what the exact symptoms are.

Comment: if i just copy that code block to xx.cs and change the private method to public, then GridViewPostimerkit.ItemsSource says error: the name does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @user5445811 Try prefixing the method name with the name of the class it is now a member of. If the new class is `xx`, try `xx.haePostimerkitPilvesta()`. Also, if you do not have an instance of `xx` handy, BOTH methods must now be static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert haePostimerkitPilvesta() to haePostimerkitPilvestaAsync() that returns a Task and set GridViewPostimerkit.ItemsSource in MainPage_Loaded() event. Now you should be able to move methods to other file as well.

```
async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewPostimerkit.ItemsSource = await haePostimerkitPilvestaAsync();
}

public static async Task<List<Postimerkit>> haePostimerkitPilvestaAsync()
{

    Uri address = new Uri("xxx.json"); //public link of our file
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
    WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    string content = ReadStreamAsString(stream);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content, typeof(List<Postimerkit>));
}

public static string ReadStreamAsString(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray(), 0, ms.ToArray().Count());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you moved the methods to a different class, but you're still calling them as if they were still a method of the same class.

By the way you'll also need to make `haePostimerkitPilvesta()` static now, if you don't have an instance of the new class handy to call it on.

```
public class A {
    public void F() {
        //  Compiler says "The name 'M' does not exist in current context."
        //  Current context is A. There is no M in A. M who? M in B or M in C?
        //  You must specify what M you mean! The compiler plays no guessing games.
        M();

        //  This will compile.
        //  Now the compiler knows where M lives and can find him.
        B.M();
    }
}

public class B {
    public static void M() {
        //  Do stuff
    }
}

public class C {
    public static void M() {
        //  Do TOTALLY DIFFERENT stuff
    }
}
```