# Background Service error while using as async Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, service, xamarin.android

I have a background service in Xamarin Android but the problem is I cannot use it as `Async` method, it gives an error.

> return type must be 'StartCommandResult' to match overridden member 'Service.OnStartCommand(Intent, StartCommandFlags, int)

The actual overridden method is `void` but to use await I have to change it to `async Task<T>` and then it produces the error. I searched everywhere but couldn't find a proper solution on this.

The code snippet for entire class is here:

```
{
 [Service(IsolatedProcess = false, Enabled = true, Label = "BackgroundNotificationService")]
class BackgroundNotificationService : Service
{
    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(BackgroundNotificationService).Name;
    static readonly int TimerWait = 3600000;
    Timer timer;
    DateTime startTime;
    bool isStarted = false;

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        timer.Dispose();
        timer = null;
        isStarted = false;

        TimeSpan runtime = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(startTime);
        Log.Info(TAG, $"Simple Service destroyed at {DateTime.UtcNow} after running for {runtime:c}.");
        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    public override async Task<StartCommandResult> OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        StartCommandResult a = StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
        Log.Debug(TAG, $"OnStartCommand called at {startTime}, flags={flags}, startid={startId}");
        if (isStarted)
        {
            TimeSpan runtime = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(startTime);
            Log.Info(TAG, $"This service was already started, it's been running for {runtime:c}.");
            await UpdateData();
        }
        else
        {
            startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            Log.Info(TAG, $"Starting the service, at {startTime}.");
            timer = new Timer(HandleTimerCallback, startTime, 0, TimerWait);
            isStarted = true;
            await UpdateData();
        }
        return a;
    }

    void HandleTimerCallback(object state)
    {
        TimeSpan runTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(startTime);
        Log.Info(TAG, $"This service has been running for {runTime:c} (since ${state}).");
    }


}
}
```

As far as I know it should work because I am returning `StartCommandResult` in override method. But if I am wrong then is there any method that I am missing? Maybe there is another way to do this and I don't know that.

**Update and Solution**

I ended up implementing another new `IntentService` class to do all the background updating work while the above service only handles the calling of the `IntentService`. The service is called with an explicit intent as any other service.

```
 public class CustomIntentService : IntentService
{
    public CustomIntentService() : base("CustomIntentService")
    {
    }

    protected override async void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        // do your work
        string servicename = typeof(CustomIntentService).Name;
        Log.Info(servicename, "Starting background work");
        try
        {
            await UpdateData();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Info(servicename, "Background work returned with errors.\nError:" + ex.Message);
            return;
        }
        Log.Info(servicename, "Background work completed without errors.");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you're asking for a change in reality, which we can't really deliver. You have a method that is expected to return with a `StartCommandResult`. You want to provide a method that will return and that will *at some later point in time* produce a `StartCommandResult`.

Comment: I have implemented the method with two separate services. One with `Service` as above and the other which actually does the all work in the background is `IntentService`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the method [`OnStartCommand`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Service.OnStartCommand/) defined in the base class [`Service`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.Service/) has return type `StartCommandResult` not `Task<StartCommandResult>`, so you cannot change the return type of a method when overriding in the child class.

You can create a proxy method if you want to make it async like:

```
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
        return OnStartCommandAsync(intent,flags,startId).Result;
}
```

and the async method would be like:

```
private async Task<StartCommandResult> OnStartCommandAsync(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
  StartCommandResult a = StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
        Log.Debug(TAG, $"OnStartCommand called at {startTime}, flags={flags}, startid={startId}");
        if (isStarted)
        {
            TimeSpan runtime = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(startTime);
            Log.Info(TAG, $"This service was already started, it's been running for {runtime:c}.");
            await UpdateData();
        }
        else
        {
            startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            Log.Info(TAG, $"Starting the service, at {startTime}.");
            timer = new Timer(HandleTimerCallback, startTime, 0, TimerWait);
            isStarted = true;
            await UpdateData();
        }
        return a;
}
```

But note that it wouldn't serve you the purpose you want, because `.Result` will block the thread until the `async` method returns the result, so it is basically the async method synchronously

For reference [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628087/calling-async-method-synchronously).

Comment: So how can I use `await` method in this service? For me this is not an answer, it is just half of it.

Comment: Still it's not helping. You need to have `async` in the overridden method to use `await` and then its return type will be `Task<T>`. So we are back at where we started from.

Comment: have you seen the latest changed post ?