# Global Variable to Store the Await Statement in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, asynchronous, .net-core

I have an await statement `await SecureStorage.GetAsync("RegisteredUserID");`, which stored the User Id, in the Xamarin Secure Storage. The `SetAsynch` and `GetAsynch` can be only used with `await` in Asynch Function.

But, In my App, in `App.xml.cs` file, there is an Synchronize Function, where I want to get the value from Secure Storage and use as the value for `options.AgentName`.

It seems like the Global Variable is one of the Solution. How could I achieve this?

```
public static IHostBuilder BuildHost(Assembly platformSpecific = null) =>
            XamarinHost.CreateDefaultBuilder<App>()
                .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddAriesFramework(builder => builder.RegisterEdgeAgent(
                        options: options =>
                        {
                            options.AgentName = "Mobile Holder";

                            // Code
                });
```

**UPDATE**

```
public string UserId { get; private set; }

protected override async void OnStart()
{
    UserId = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("RegisteredPIN");
}
```

Comment: just create a property on your App class

Comment: `Application.Current.Properties["RegisteredPIN"] = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("RegisteredPIN");` makes the `public App()` red.. how could I use the Await Statement in `App()` (which is non-asynch)...

Comment: create a C# property, and then set if in the OnStart method, not the constructor

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628087/calling-async-method-synchronously

Comment: @Jason I add the code above, kindly have a look.. I created the property and set it in the OnStart Method.. how could I use it value for `options.AgentName`... thanks :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

create a public property in `App` and set it's value in `OnStart`

```
public string UserId { get; private set; }

protected override async void OnStart()
{
    UserId = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("RegisteredPIN");
}
```

then anywhere in your app you can access the value

```
((App)App.Current).UserId
```

Comment: Questionable suggestion - first of all this is exactly the same code show in the question... and it does not in any way guarantee that `UserId` will be available when needed (nor give any way to know if it actually obtained the value or not)...