# I'm having problems with async

Tags: c#, async-await, multiplayer

[documentation](https://doc.stride3d.net/latest/en/api/Stride.Engine.Network.SocketMessageLayer.html#Stride_Engine_Network_SocketMessageLayer_SendReceiveAsync_Stride_Engine_Network_SocketMessage_) I was reading

it is written: `public Task<SocketMessage> SendReceiveAsync(SocketMessage query)`

in source code is: `public async Task<SocketMessage> SendReceiveAsync(SocketMessage query){...}`

what I'm trying to understand is how do I call it and how it works. anything I try I get errors.

what I'm trying to do is send and receive message from server. I've been working on this for weeks now I've been also reading [How and when to use ‘async’ and ‘await’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await) but I can't manage to get it work.

this is what I managed to make.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Stride.Core.Mathematics;
using Stride.Input;
using Stride.Engine;
using Stride.Engine.Network;
using System.IO;

namespace MyGame
{
    public class Net : SyncScript
    {
        string str = "";
        public Stream socket;
        public SimpleSocket SS;
        public SocketMessage SM;
        public SocketMessageLayer SML;
        public void Server(){
            SML = new SocketMessageLayer(SS, true);
            //int port, bool singleConnection, int retryCount = 1
            SS.StartServer(21, true, 1);
        }
        public void Client(){
            SML = new SocketMessageLayer(SS, false);
            //string address, int port, bool needAck = true
            SS.StartClient("127.0.0.1", 21, true);
        }
        
        
        Task<SocketMessage> SendReceiveAsync(SocketMessage query){
            //here I need to return somehow as I get error: not all code paths return a value
            return query; // Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Stride.Engine.Network.SocketMessage' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Stride.Engine.Network.SocketMessage>'
        }
        public async Task ReceiveMessage(){
            // you still need to get the query from somewhere...
            SocketMessage result = await SML.SendReceiveAsync(SM);

        
            //[abbreviated] // if I uncomment this I get: Error: ; expected
                                                    //Error: Invalid expression term '}'
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        
        public override void Start(){
        }
        public override void Update()
        {
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
inside code I've explained what I tried and what doesn't work

Comment: Delete the `Task<SocketMessage> SendReceiveAsync(SocketMessage query);` line, which looks like a local function with no body, and use parentheses after `await SendReceiveAsync` to call the method. Without the parenthesis, this is a method group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change ReceiveMessage, so the compiler not mean you want to declare a method called SendReceiveAsync. From the documentation you posted you want to call it on SocketMessageLayer so try:

```
    public async Task<SocketMessage> ReceiveMessage()
    {
        //and now we call await on the task 
        SocketMessage result = await SML.SendReceiveAsync;
        return result;
    }
```

by the way, according to the documentation SML.Send is also async so you should redefine:

```
    public async Task SendMessage(string str){
         await SML.Send(str);
    }
```

Or if you want to call it in a sync way (what I would not recommend) try:

```
    public void SendMessage(string str){
         SML.Send(str).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

See [Calling async method synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628087/calling-async-method-synchronously/22629216)

Comment: here I get errors:

[C:\programming\Stride 3D\MyGame\MyGame\Net.cs(38,13)]: Error: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<Task>'.
[C:\programming\Stride 3D\MyGame\MyGame\Net.cs(37,21)]: Error: 'Net.SendMessage(string)': not all code paths return a value
[C:\programming\Stride 3D\MyGame\MyGame\Net.cs(42,36)]: Error: Cannot await 'method group'

Comment: Sorry, the SendMessage (with await) needs to be async while the sync one needs to return void. I changed my samples.

Answer (score 2):

It's giving you an error, as it should, because that is incorrect syntax. What is `SendReceiveAsync` part supposed to be?

You are not declaring that function anywhere in your class so either:

**You declare the function somewhere in your class (outside of your function)**:

```
Task<SocketMessage> SendReceiveAsync(SocketMessage query)
{
   //do logic
}
```

and then you can call it from your function, like you would any other function:

```
public async Task ReceiveMessage()
{
// still need to provide a query
     SocketMessage result = await SendReceiveAsync(query);
     //int result = await longRunningTask;
     //use the result 
     //Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

**You reference the class in which this function is declared**:

Maybe this function you are trying to use is already declared in one of your class members. Maybe in the `SimpleSocket` class?
If so try this:

```
public async Task ReceiveMessage()
{
    // you still need to get the query from somewhere...
    SocketMessage result = await SML.SendReceiveAsync(query);


    [abbreviated]
}
```

What you are trying to do makes little sense, because you are declaring a function inside another function and then attempting to call this function from inside that same function. Furthermore, you are trying to call a function that is not declared anywhere. So it looks like you need to brush up on actual syntax before jumping onto more complicated stuff.