# Calling Entity Framework async code, synchronously, within a lock

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core

I have an async method which will load some info from the database via Entity Framework.

In one circumstance I want to call that code synchronously from within a lock.

Do I need two copies of the code, one async, one not, or is there a way of calling the async code synchronously?

For example something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new Test().Go();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    private object someLock = new object();

    public void Go()
    {
        lock(someLock)
        {
            Task<int> task = Task.Run(async () => await DoSomethingAsync()); 
            var result = task.Result;
        }
    }
    
    public async Task<int> DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        // This will make a database call
        return await Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: as a number of the comments are saying the same thing, I thought I'd elaborate a little

**Background**: normally, trying to do this is a bad idea. Lock and async are polar opposites as documented in lots of places, there's no reason to have an async call in a lock.

So why do it here? I can make the database call synchronously but that requires duplicating some methods which isn't ideal. Ideally the language would let you call the same method synchronously or asynchronously

**Scenario**: this is a Web API. The application starts, a number of Web API calls execute and they all want some info that's in the database that's provided by a service provider dedicated for that purpose (i.e. a call added via `AddScoped` in the `Startup.cs`). Without something like a lock they will all try to get the info from the database. EF Core is only relevant in that every other call to the database is async, this one is the exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling async method synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628087/calling-async-method-synchronously)

Comment: My advice would be to just not use synchronous code in the first place. Can't you do some refactoring to just do everything properly?

Comment: You can't use async code in locks, and it needs a lock

Comment: I didn't know if the lock introduced some subtle gotcha that I would need to be aware of, which makes it slightly different to the other question

Comment: @tony I'm guessing that it doesn't need a lock; it needs *synchronization*, and you're familiar with using `lock` for that - but: it isn't the only option.

Comment: @tony how is EF Core involved with this question? It sounds like your real problem is very different. Why would you even need a lock if you can use `await context.SaveChangesAsync` to persist all pending changes in a single transaction? Are you trying to use a singleton DbContext in multiple threads? Did you try to speed up slow operations by "parallelizing" them instead of finding and fixing the actual delays?

Comment: `lock` has no effect on synchronous or asynchronous execution. It only locks a block of code to be executed by one thread at a time

Comment: @tony `it needs a lock` why? DbContext doesn't need locks - it's not meant to be used by multiple threads *at all*. That's not an issue for the job it's meant to do though - a Unit of Work for Object to Relational Mapping. It's not a database connection

Comment: It needs a lock because there's a slow stored procedure which needs to be called once at startup, via EFCore, but many handlers called asynchronously need the result of that call

Comment: @tony then a lock won't help at all, and EF Core shouldn't even be used. A lock won't prevent other threads, applications or web requests from calling the same stored procedure. To call a stored procedure all you need is plain old ADO.NET. You could use Dapper to reduce the 10 lines needed by ADO.NET to just `connection.ExecuteAsync("myproc",new {param1=123})`

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. If anything else wants to call that stored procedure they can, that's not the issue. The issue is we need the SP to be called and the result stored, cached, and available to other handlers.

Comment: @tony the question you posted has nothing to do with the real problem. EF Core isn't even relevant, locking won't help. What kind of application are you building? What do you mean by handlers? It matters. If you have a .NET Core app, you could use a Singleton or BackgroundService to execute that stored procedure, ensuring that only the BackgroundService itself could start loading and caching the result. No need to lock  in that case. You could also use `Lazy<T>` on a singleton to only load the data once. There are a lot of ways to do this that don't involve locking

Comment: This is a Web.API app. The application starts, a number of web.api calls execute and they all want some info that's in the database that's provided by a service provider dedicated for that purpose (i.e. a call added via AddScoped in the Startup.cs). Without something like a lock they will all try to get the info from the db. EF Core is only relevant in that every other call to the db is async, this one is the exception

Comment: _"Without something like a lock they will all try to get the info from the database."_ and what is the problem here? Isn't it how it is supposed to work?

Comment: The info is the same for all the calls, it's shared. Multiple reads would be inefficient. Only one is needed

Answer (score 3):

You simply cannot use a `lock` with asynchronous code; the entire point of `async`/`await` is to switch *away* from a strict thread-based model, but `lock` aka `System.Monitor` **is entirely thread focused**. Frankly, you also shouldn't  *attempt* to synchronously call asynchronous code; that is simply not valid, and no "solution" is correct.

`SemaphoreSlim` makes a good alternative to `lock` as an asynchronous-aware synchronization primitve. However, you should *either* acquire/release the semaphore *inside* the `async` operation in your `Task.Run`, or you should make your `Go` an asynchronous method, i.e. `public async Task GoAsync()`, and do the same there; of course, at that point it becomes redundant to use `Task.Run`, so: just execute `await DoSomethingAsync()` directly:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim someLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
public async Task GoAsync()
{
    await someLock.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        await DoSomethingAsync();
    }
    finally
    {
        someLock.Release();
    }
}
```

If the `try`/`finally` bothers you; perhaps cheat!

```
public async Task GoAsync()
{
    using (await someLock.LockAsync())
    {
        await DoSomethingAsync();
    }
}
```

with

```cs
internal static class SemaphoreExtensions
{
    public static ValueTask<SemaphoreToken> LockAsync(this SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
    {
        // try to take synchronously
        if (semaphore.Wait(0)) return new(new SemaphoreToken(semaphore));

        return SlowLockAsync(semaphore);

        static async ValueTask<SemaphoreToken> SlowLockAsync(SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            return new(semaphore);
        }
    }
}
internal readonly struct SemaphoreToken : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;
    public void Dispose() => _semaphore?.Release();
    internal SemaphoreToken(SemaphoreSlim semaphore) => _semaphore = semaphore;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem. If the OP is trying to access DbContext from multiple threads, or trying to "speed up" bulk operations, SemaphoreSlim won't help

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos indeed; sharing a DB-context (or a connection) already sounds like a bad idea, and usually leads to unbounded memory growth (due to tracking), plus heavily constrained throughput (due to sunchronization)