# Calling an async method and returning a value in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Is there an easy way in .net to wait for an async function to fetch its returned result?

I wrote code like this but maybe there is a standard solution?

```
T WaitForResult<T>(Func<Task<T>> async)
{
    Task<T> task = async.Invoke();
    task.Wait();
    return task.Result;
}
```

e.g.

```
async Task<string> f()
{
...
}
```

```
void g()
{
    string str = WaitForResult( () => f() );
}
```

If we use await instead that, the `g` function would have to be marked as async. How to avoid this?

Comment: Yes, the `await` operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await

Comment: The Microsoft docs have a well-written series of articles on [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) that are worth the read.

Comment: BTW, using `await` like that (which is the correct way) doesn't do what you probably think it does. However it does act (or appear to act) as if it does

Comment: Related: [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c) and also [Calling async method synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628087/calling-async-method-synchronously).

Answer (score 1):

```
async Task<string> f()
{
...
}
```

Is called by

```
string s = await f();
```

If you are calling from a non async function and you cannot change this you can use.

```
string s = f().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

or

```
string s = f().Result;
```

But this is not recommend as it kinda brakes the async pattern.

Comment: But then the method where we use await operator must be marked as async. How to avoid this?