# How to ensure different CultureInfo.CurrentCulture for calls to specific library

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, task-parallel-library, cultureinfo

I have a 3rd party library that uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` but it must be set to `InvariantCulture` to function properly.

My multithreaded application uses localized `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.

```cs
public string WrappedCallTo3rdPartyLibrary(string input)
{
    //use new thread to isolate CurrentCulture side effects.
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        string result = _3rdPartyLibrary.SynchronousCall(input);
        return result;
    }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

1. Is this proper way to set culture info for _3rdPartyLibrary?
2. Do I have a guarantee that the above approach does not affect the parent thread?

EDIT:

I originally tried synchronous call, but I suspect it had side effects (parent or previously started child threads affected?)

```cs
public string WrappedCallTo3rdPartyLibrary(string input)
{
    var ciBackup = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    try
    {
       CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
       return _3rdPartyLibrary.SynchronousCall(input);
    }
    finally
    { 
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = ciBackup ;
    }
}
```

Comment: The correct solution, the one used in all .NET classes, is to pass the CultureInfo as a parameter. All `Parse`, `TryParse`, `ToString`, `Format` methods take a CultureInfo or IFormatProvider parameter

Comment: What does the real code do? Why `Task.Factory.StartNew`? Setting the task thread's CI was used way back in 2010-12, before `async/await` started preserving the CultureInfo. You can use `Thread.CurrentCulture =  = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;` but you must ensure it's returned to its original value, otherwise the next task that runs on this thread will run with an unexpected CI.

Comment: What culture does the *parent* thread or application use? What happens if you *don't* set the culture at all? In .NET Core, only the Invariant Culture is included by default, to reduce the deployment size. Unless you set `<InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>` in csproj or `DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false` in the build environment, everything will run using the Invariant culture

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I've raised feature request for `CultureInfo` as a parameter two years ago ;)  My application culture uses `,` as decimal separator and it is working fine in production. See my edit for reason why I start new `Task`

Comment: @​​Magnus out of curiosity why did you delete [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77437336/how-to-ensure-different-cultureinfo-currentculture-for-calls-to-specific-library/77437685#77437685)? I would upvoted it if I could!

Comment: So does mine, but that's only a problem when trying to parse strings or format numbers. It doesn't affect `double` or `decimal` values themselves. You haven't explained what's wrong with the current code either. The `finally` clause takes care of side effects by *reverting* to the original culture. You have to use that `finally` in the Task delegate too

Comment: What kind of application is this? If it's a web app, using tasks just to change the culture is wasteful. Every request in a web app is served by a separate threadpool thread, just like tasks. The question's code blocks the request thread without providing any benefits.  ASP.NET Core provides [multiple strategies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/select-language-culture?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to control the culture used during an entire request through middleware, request headers, user options or custom code

Comment: It's a **Blazor Server**, which does not have thread per request or per session. It's more like thread pre user interaction. I occasionally got `FormatException` but couldn't repeat it with the same input. The library evaluates excel like formulas

Answer (score -1):

The synchronous call you suggest should not have side effects even if it is executed on the thread pool, i.e. in a task.

As a side note, you should avoid `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();`.  Better use `Task.Wait()` and `Task.Result`.

UPDATE

Let me quote the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter?view=net-7.0#remarks):

> This method is intended for compiler use rather than use directly in code.

Comment: Why is Wait() better then GetAwaiter().GetResult()?

Comment: @Liero, see the updated answer above.

Comment: The `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` [is better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628087/calling-async-method-synchronously/40855230#40855230).

Comment: Still, the documentation is not recommending this.  Unless there is a strong reason to so, I would avoid `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.  In this particular case I do not see such one.